# How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, git-submodules

Note: while the use-case described is about using submodules within a project, the same applies to a normal `git clone` of a repository over HTTP.

I have a project under Git control.  I'd like to add a submodule:

```
git submodule add http://github.com/jscruggs/metric_fu.git vendor/plugins/metric_fu
```

But I get

```
...
got 1b0313f016d98e556396c91d08127c59722762d0
got 4c42d44a9221209293e5f3eb7e662a1571b09421
got b0d6414e3ca5c2fb4b95b7712c7edbf7d2becac7
error: Unable to find abc07fcf79aebed56497e3894c6c3c06046f913a under http://github.com/jscruggs/metri...
Cannot obtain needed commit abc07fcf79aebed56497e3894c6c3c06046f913a
while processing commit ee576543b3a0820cc966cc10cc41e6ffb3415658.
fatal: Fetch failed.
Clone of 'http://github.com/jscruggs/metric_fu.git' into submodule path 'vendor/plugins/metric_fu'
```

I have my HTTP_PROXY set up:

```
c:\project> echo %HTTP_PROXY%
http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

I even have a global Git setting for the http proxy:

```
c:\project> git config --get http.proxy
http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

Has anybody gotten HTTP fetches to consistently work through a proxy?  What's really strange is that a few project on GitHub work fine ([`awesome_nested_set`](http://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set/) for example), but others consistently fail ([rails](http://github.com/rails/rails/) for example).

Comment: Could your proxy be censoring some words or something, thereby only affecting those repos where those words happen to show up as part of the byte stream?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting git to work with a proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Comment: @alvaro, I think you mean that [Getting git to work with a proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) is a possible duplicate of this question.  This question is older than the one to which you refer.

Comment: @James, your "global" Git setting for the proxy server is not actually global, but local. To be global, you need to supply argument `--global` to `git config`.

Comment: And just in case if anybody would wonder why would git ignore proxy settings: make sure you're working with the address *not* with git protocol, i.e. change **git**://github.com/SomeProject/foo.git → **https**://github.com/SomeProject/foo.git

Comment: @DerekMahar Older questions may be closed of duplicates of newer questions, if the newer question is better quality (or more generally applicatble).

Answer (score 139, accepted):

What finally worked was setting the `http_proxy` environment variable.  I had set `HTTP_PROXY` correctly, but Git apparently likes the lower-case version better.

Comment: Does setting `http.proxy` in the global Git configuration work?  In your question, you set `http.proxy` in the local repository configuration.

Comment: In my case I had to set the `https_proxy`

Comment: `https.proxy` seemed to work for me as I was using https over github

Comment: @MSmith If you had to set `https_proxy` this means you were using `https` not `http` which question is about.

Comment: Curl and libcurl don't recognize uppercase HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY. See this link for more info: http://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2001-12/0034.html

Comment: set $all_proxy environment variable is also ok.

Comment: The "$http_proxy" environment variable is the http_proxy environment variable.

Comment: Didn't work for me. On the other hand, the solution from user 'Max MacLeod' worked (git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain...).

Comment: Failed for me with: "The requested URL returned error: 501"

Answer (score 639):

You can also set the HTTP proxy that Git uses in global configuration property `http.proxy`:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

To authenticate with the proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080/
```

(Credit goes to [@EugeneKulabuhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/215809/eugene-kulabuhov) and [@JaimeReynoso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3067848/jaime-reynoso) for the authentication format.)

Comment: This worked for me: Set HTTP_PROXY in environment for user (on Windows), then the above comment with $HTTP_PROXY (uppercase). +1 for this solution.

Comment: CleverCoder, on Windows, you need to specify %HTTP_PROXY%, not $HTTP_PROXY (unless you're running Cygwin, of course).  I will edit my answer to work in Windows instead of a Unix environment.

Comment: Use `git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080` syntax to provide username/password

Comment: @JFA, I'm not sure I completely agree with your edit.  Yes, the command you added does work on a Linux system, but the original question referred not to Linux, but to Windows.

Comment: @DerekMahar I don't see anything saying windows in the original post, but also, I reached this question from Google, saw that you used to have a linux answer, but deleted it, and had to search through the edits to find the difference, so my though was that if you already have the linux answer, and this question is getting a massive amount of traffic, you might as well have a multisystem solution.

Comment: @JFA, the question doesn't mention Windows directly, but implies Windows because it refers to Windows drive letters.

Comment: @JFA, it's also important to point out that in order for your Linux command to work, the user must define environment variable `http_proxy`.  The question clearly states that Windows environment variable `HTTP_PROXY` is defined which is why the Windows part of the answer refers to `%HTTP_PROXY%`.  We cannot make the same assumption about shell variable `http_proxy`.

Comment: @JFA, I edited the answer so that it explicitly sets the environment variables before they are used.

Comment: For anyone who might be having problems with the proxy, http://<UserID>:<Password>@<ProxyURL>:<Port>/ worked for me

Comment: @Mr.Hyde, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265463/reset-git-proxy-to-default-configuration.

Comment: @DerekMahar, I don't want to sound "picky" but the first command in the "Linux" section of your answer does not set an **environment (or global) variable**. It sets a local shell variable. I mention this as _git_ uses _curl_ to fetch data over http(s) and _curl_ can be directed using environment variables to use a proxy. Strangely, to specify the http proxy, _curl_ accepts the **http_proxy** environment variable in lowercase only. Therefore I think your answer and comment might be misleading to people that are looking for an answer to set the environment variable to make _git_ use a proxy.

Comment: @DanielK., thank you for explaining why James A. Rosen's answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/397642/107158) works!  I hadn't known that *curl* reads lowercase environment variable `http_proxy`.  The reason I used the local shell variables was not to be misleading, but to refer to the original question which refers to `%HTTP_PROXY%` and because JFA edited my answer to include a Windows specific solution that also referred to `%HTTP_PROXY%`.

Comment: However, since the Windows and Linux solutions differ only in the format of variable `HTTP_PROXY`, and this variable is not essential to the answer and adds only redundant information, I will merge the two commands together into a single, platform agnostic command.

Comment: One most important thing is that even using this, or $http_proxy, it only works when cloning with `https`, not with `ssh`!! That's what took me so long to find out. Hope it helps others with it

Answer (score 152):

There are some great answers on this already. However, I thought I would chip in as some proxy servers require you to authenticate with a user Id and password. Sometimes this can be on a domain.

So, for example if your proxy server configuration is as follows:

```
Server: myproxyserver
Port: 8080
Username: mydomain\myusername
Password: mypassword
```

Then, add to your `.gitconfig` file, using the following command:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080
```

Don't worry about `https`. As long as the specified proxy server supports HTTP, and HTTPS, then one entry in the configuration file will suffice.

You can then verify that the command added the entry to your `.gitconfig` file successfully by doing `cat .gitconfig`:

At the end of the file, you will see an entry as follows:

```
[http]
       proxy = http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080
```

That's it!

Comment: Interesting. I am able to get to the "Resolving deltas" portion with 100% but then it looks like the clone process just hangs.  Anyone experienced that?

Comment: +1. And soon, you will be able [to setup proxy per url!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309)

Comment: @apoplexy can you comment on your suggested edit please so I can consider

Comment: If you have @ symbol in your username or password, then you can URL encode it `%40` and it will work.

Comment: Instead of cat .gitconfig, you can list the config settings with git config --list

Answer (score 70):

If you just want to use a proxy on a specified repository, and don't need on other repositories, the preferable way is the `-c, --config <key=value>` option when you `git clone` a repository.

E.g.,

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git --config "http.proxy=proxyHost:proxyPort"
```

Comment: This is strange, I tried setting $http_proxy, but git didn't respect it. Looks like it only cares about its own config...

Comment: Works. You can also specify `--config` multiple times, e.g. when you also want to set `https.proxy`.

Comment: clone with proxy config but without changing the proxy config of the user. Exactly what I need ! Thx.

Comment: --config "core.gitProxy..." howto,I want to proxy ssh protocol without global proxy seting, thx.@alijandro

Answer (score 55):

It looks like you're using a [MinGW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinGW) compile of Git on Windows (or possibly another one I haven't heard about).  There are ways to debug this: I believe all of the HTTP proxy work for Git is done by [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL). Set this environment variable before running Git:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

This should at least give you an idea of what is going on behind the scenes.

Comment: When I add this environment variable, msysgit doesn't print out anything extra. :(

Comment: after fighting with proxies for some time, this tip helped me find out that curl's cert database was missing/messed up, and THAT was why requests were failing.

Answer (score 26):

When your network team does SSL inspection by rewriting certificates, then using an HTTP URL instead of an HTTPS one, combined with setting this variable worked for me.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy:8081
```

Comment: You can also add this to the environment to accept the rewritten certificates that the network dudes offer to inspect your traffic:     export GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true

Comment: Worked for me perfectly.  Thanks.  I just had to add


git config --global http.proxy http://proxy:8081


git config --global https.proxy http://proxy:8081

Comment: Thanks to @sethbc, @datasmid! I needed GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 to debug and GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true to skip the verification.

Comment: not working with me. not even with the GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY var

Answer (score 21):

For me the git://  just doesn't work through the proxy although the https:// does.   This caused some bit of headache because I was running scripts that all used git:// so I couldn't just easily change them all.   However I found this GEM

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git://github.com/
```

Comment: I know that I also had problems to pull from git://. Have you considered a SSH key problem? My problem was due to a bad SSH key configuration.

Answer (score 20):

You could also **edit the** ***.gitconfig*** **file** located in the `%userprofile%` directory on a Windows system (*notepad %userprofile%.gitconfig*) or in the `~` directory on a Linux system (*vi ~/.gitconfig*) and **add an HTTP section** as below.

Content of the *.gitconfig* file:

```
[http]
        proxy = http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

Answer (score 18):

If you are on Windows, consider setting HTTPS_PROXY as well if you are retrieving via an https URL. It worked for me!

Comment: It was enough to set `https_proxy` environment variable alone (no git global or repo proxy option set) in my case (msysgit on Windows XP).

Answer (score 14):

I find neither `http.proxy` nor `GIT_PROXY_COMMAND` work for my authenticated HTTP proxy. The proxy is not triggered in either way. But I find a way to work around this.

1. Install [corkscrew](http://www.agroman.net/corkscrew/), or other alternatives you want.
2. Create a authfile. The format for `authfile` is: `user_name:password`, and `user_name`, `password` is your username and password to access your proxy.   To create such a file, simply run command like this: `echo "username:password" > ~/.ssh/authfile`.
3. Edit `~/.ssh/config`, and make sure its permission is `644`: `chmod 644 ~/.ssh/config`

Take github.com as an example, add the following lines to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host    github.com
        HostName        github.com
        ProxyCommand    /usr/local/bin/corkscrew <your.proxy> <proxy port> %h %p <path/to/authfile>
        User            git
```

Now whenever you do anything with `git@github.com`, it will use the proxy automatically. You can easily do the same thing to [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org) as well.

This is not so elegant as other approaches, but it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on step 2, "create a authfile"? It seems like your approach is the only one that will work for git:// urls.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows, if you don't want to put your password in .gitconfig in the plain text, you can use

- Cntml (http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/)

It authenticates you against normal or even Windows [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTLM) proxy and starts localhost-proxy without authentication.

In order to get it run:

- Install Cntml
- Configure Cntml according to documentation to pass your proxy authentication
- Point Git to your new [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) proxy:

  ```
  [http]
      proxy = http://localhost:3128  # Change port number as necessary
  ```

Comment: For what it's worth, this should've been the accepted answer, he's on windows. There isn't a transparent proxy (otherwise there would not be a problem.

Answer (score 11):

Set Git *credential.helper* to *wincred*.

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Make sure there is only one credential.helper

```
git config -l
```

If there is more than one, and it's not set to *wincred* remove it.

```
git config --system --unset credential.helper
```

Now set the proxy without any password.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<YOUR WIN LOGIN NAME>@proxy:80
```

Check that all the settings that you added looks good....

```
git config --global -l
```

Now you are good to go!

Answer (score 9):

For me this worked:

```
sudo apt-get install socat
```

Create a file inside your $BIN_PATH/gitproxy with:

```
#!/bin/sh
_proxy=192.168.192.1
_proxyport=3128
exec socat STDIO PROXY:$_proxy:$1:$2,proxyport=$_proxyport
```

Don’t forget to give it execution permissions:

```
chmod a+x gitproxy
```

Run the following commands to set up the environment:

```
export PATH=$BIN_PATH:$PATH
git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy
```

Comment: Link to an explanation and a link to a gist with updates to the (mini-)script: http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/

Comment: This answer is the only one that works for `git://` protocol URLs, for those (rare) git servers that don't support https. Also works on windows, with an appropriate batch file and socat for windows.

Answer (score 8):

#### Set up proxy to Git

##### Command

```
git config --global http.proxy http://user:password@domain:port
```

##### Example

```
git config --global http.proxy http://clairton:123456@proxy.clairtonluz.com.br:8080
```

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, with a slightly different fix: ***rebuilding Git with HTTP support***

The `git:` protocol did not work through my corporate firewall.

For example, this timed out:

```
git clone git://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server.git
```

`curl github.com` works just fine, though, so I know my `http_proxy` environment variable is correct.

I tried using `http`, like below, but I got an immediate error.

```
git clone http://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server.git

->>>  fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http' <<<-
```

I tried recompiling Git like so:

```
./configure  --with-curl --with-expat
```

But still I got the fatal error.

Finally, after several frustrating hours, I read the configure file, and saw this:

> # Define CURLDIR=/foo/bar if your curl header and library files are in

> # /foo/bar/include and /foo/bar/lib directories.

I remembered then, that I had not complied `curl` from source, and so went looking for the header files.  Sure enough, they were not installed. That was the problem. Make did not complain about the missing header files. So I did not realize that the `--with-curl` option did nothing (it is, in fact the default in my version of `git`).

I did the following to fix it:

1. Added the headers needed for make:

   yum install curl-devel
   (expat-devel-1.95.8-8.3.el5_5.3.i386  was already installed).
2. Removed `git` from `/usr/local` (as I want the new install to live there).

```
I simply removed `git*` from `/usr/local/share` and `/usr/local/libexec`
```

3. Searched for the include directories containing the `curl` and `expat` header files, and then (because I had read through `configure`) added these to the environment like so:

   export CURLDIR=/usr/include
   export EXPATDIR=/usr/include
4. Ran `configure` with the following options, which, again, were described in the `configure` file itself, and were also the defaults but what the heck:

   ./configure  --with-curl --with-expat
5. And now `http` works with `git` through my corporate firewall:

   git clone http://github.com/miksago/node-websocket-server.git
   Cloning into 'node-websocket-server'...

   - Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file, using defaults
   - About to connect() to proxy proxy.entp.attws.com port 8080
   - Trying 135.214.40.30... * connected
     ...

Comment: I'd glad you put this one forward, I didn't realise that the git protocol wasn't being handled on my squid proxy

Answer (score 6):

This worked to me.

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy_user:proxy_passwd@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

Answer (score 5):

This blog post I found solves the problem for me by updating the curl certificates.

*[GitHub, CA errors and old curl's](http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2011/06/github_ssl_ca_errors.html)*

Comment: Halleluyah, this plus `git config --global http.sslcainfo NEW_CERTS_BUNDLE.crt` as described in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8248484/98528 did it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use [proxychains](http://proxychains.sourceforge.net/)

```
proxychains git pull ...
```

But proxychains is discontinued. Use [proxychains-ng](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng) instead.

Comment: unfortunately Unix only

Comment: @Samoth Jun,  for windows your may want try [SocksCap64](https://www.sockscap64.com/en/)

Answer (score 4):

Worth to mention:
Most examples on the net show [examples like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40210253)

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy_user:proxy_passwd@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

So it seems, that  - if your proxy needs authentication - you **must** leave your company-password in the git-config. Which isn't really cool.

But, if you just configure the user without password:

```
git config --global http.proxy proxy_user@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

Git seems (at least on my Windows-machine without credentials-helper) to recognize that and prompts for the proxy-password on repo-access.

Comment: You are my man, as my sso company username and password have so much special simboles that was quite impossibile to encode and get through. With this "escamotage" I was able to provide the password on the clone face or any other next steps after have set the proxy address.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
git config --add http.proxy http://user:password@proxy_host:proxy_port
```

Answer (score 3):

The below method works for me:

```
echo 'export http_proxy=http://username:password@roxy_host:port/' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'export https_proxy=http://username:password@roxy_host:port' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

- Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshenv file instead of ~/.bash_profile.
- Ubuntu and Fedora note: Modify your ~/.bashrc file instead of ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to set up a proxy for a specific URL, see the [http.<url>.* section](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httplturlgt) in the `git config` manual. For example, for `https://github.com/` one can do

```
git config --global 'http.https://github.com/.proxy' http://proxy.mycompany:80
```

Answer (score 2):

For Windows

Go to → *C:/Users/user_name/gitconfig*

Update the gitconfig file with the below details:

```
[http]

[https]

    proxy = https://your_proxy:your_port

[http]

    proxy = http://your_proxy:your_port
```

**How can you check your proxy and port number?**

*Internet Explorer* → *Settings* → *Internet Options* → *Connections* → *LAN Settings*

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with your proxy.  It's a problem with GitHub (or Git).  It fails for me on Git 1.6.0.1 on Linux as well.  [Bug](http://logicalawesome.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8570/tickets/992-git-submodule-add-fails) is already reported (by you no less).

Make sure to delete your pasties; they're already on Google. But I guess you can't delete them. Use [Gist](http://gist.github.com/) instead?

Comment: I posted to github and msysGit as well b/c I wasn't sure where the problem lay.

I can't seem to delete pasties, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

$http_proxy is for http://github.com.... 
$https_proxy is for https://github.com...

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers worked for me when my proxy didn't need authentication. If you are using proxy which requires you to authenticate then you may try CCProxy. I have small tutorial on how to set it up here,

http://blog.praveenkumar.co.in/2012/09/proxy-free-windows-xp78-and-mobiles.html

I was able to push, pull, create new repositories. Everything worked just fine. Make sure you do a clean uninstall and reinstall of new version if you are facing issues with Git like I did.

Comment: The link is broken: *"Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site. We can’t connect to the server at blog.praveenkumar.co.in."*

Answer (score 0):

I got around the proxy using https... some proxies don't even check https.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

c:\git\meantest>git clone http://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
Cloning into 'mean'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/linnovate/mean.git/': Failed connect
to github.com:80; No error

c:\git\meantest>git clone https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
Cloning into 'mean'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 2587, done.
remote: Counting objects: 27, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24/24), done.
rRemote: Total 2614 (delta 3), reused 4 (delta 0)eceiving objects:  98% (2562/26

Receiving objects: 100% (2614/2614), 1.76 MiB | 305.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1166/1166), done.
Checking connectivity... done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
      export HTTP_PROXY="http://USER:PASS@proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
```

If you have any special characters in the user/password use [url_encode](https://superuser.com/questions/273799/how-to-use-special-characters-in-username-password-for-http-proxy).

Answer (score 0):

As @user2188765 has already pointed out, try replacing the `git://` protocol of the repository with `http[s]://`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36469864/1150303).

Answer (score 0):

Recently, if I use Git clone with an HTTP address,

```
git clone --config "http.proxy=http://<ip>:<port>" https://github.com/<username>/<reponame>.git
```

GitHub will require a username and password.
And then it says this authentication method is no longer used, because it is not safe.

So, if I use the SSH method to Git clone, things will work.
I noticed that SSH will not work like this:

```
git clone --config "http.proxy=http://<ip>:<port>" git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
```

SSH with a proxy works like this:

```
# Edit ~/.ssh/config and paste the text below:
Host github.com
    Hostname ssh.github.com
    Port 443
    ProxyCommand nc -X connect -x <ip>:<port> %h %p
```

After editing the config file, the SSH proxy will work:

```
git clone git@github.com:<username>/<reponame>.git
```

mention that configuration file.

I don’t understand why it’s 443 port instead of 22.
Just ChatGPT (using GPT-4) told me, and it works for me.