# How to use git behind a proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I am using msysgit from behind a proxy. As I said in question [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

I have set system variable `http_proxy` to a value. Later I call

```
git config --global http.proxy $http_proxy
```

However, if I call something like:

```
git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gnuprologjava.git
```

It gives the following error:

```
git.savannah.gnu.org[0; 140.186.70.72]: errno=No error
fatal: unable to connect a socket (No error)
```

Comment: this works only in my corporate proxy environment which access external IP with port 22 is blocked: http://alpengeist-de.blogspot.com.au/2012/03/github-with-cygwin-git-behind-corporate.html

Comment: That's not a dupe. That question use `http(s)` url to clone while this one use `git://`.

Answer (score 23):

If you're behind an http proxy, you should be using http git urls. The [UsingGit](http://savannah.gnu.org/maintenance/UsingGit) page on Savannah.gnu.org tells you the correct syntax for this. For that repo:

```
git clone http://git.savannah.gnu.org/r/gnuprologjava.git
```

Comment: Unfortunately, some build scripts (eg for Mono) have git:// urls baked in. :(

Comment: or begin with https://

Comment: Note: By HTTP(s) it is not possible to authorize by SSH key. :-(

Answer (score 7):

When you are on linux, see [this page](http://www.emilsit.net/blog/archives/how-to-use-the-git-protocol-through-a-http-connect-proxy/).

On windows I have solved it this way;

Install [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/), and select the socat package. Create a script gitproxy.cmd and save it in the path (I used C:\msysgit\cmd\gitproxy.cmd):

```
@echo off
C:\cygwin\bin\socat.exe - PROXY:192.168.100.1:\%1:\%2,proxyport=3128
```

(replace 192.168.100.1 and 3128 with your own proxy ip/port)

Execute the following line to configure the proxy:

```
git config --global core.gitproxy gitproxy.cmd
```

Note that the proxy server must accept the CONNECT command for the git port (9418). I have added the following lines to the squid configuration to make this work:

```
acl SSL_ports port 9418         # git
acl Safe_ports port 9418        # git
```

(ie configure port 9418 the same way as port 443 in the proxy server)

Comment: FYI, if you're cloning from a git server that has an http git address, I was able to use cygwin's git by simply setting the `http_proxy` shell variable to my proxy server and then doing `git clone http://github.com/blah/blah.git`.  You can test that `http_proxy` is working through your proxy by also installing `wget` through cygwin's setup.exe and doing `wget www.google.com`.  If `http_proxy` is set correctly, that command will download a file.

Answer (score 4):

As this was answered by many but this is just for a **Windows** USER who is behind a proxy with auth.

Re-Installing (first failed, don't remove).

```
Go to: 
1. msysgit\installer-tmp\etc\gitconfig
    Under [http]
        proxy = http://user:pass@url:port
2. msysgit\installer-tmp\setup-msysgit.sh
      export HTTP_PROXY="http://USER:PASS@proxy.abc.com:8080"
```

if you have any special char in user/pass use [url_encode](https://superuser.com/questions/273799/how-to-use-special-characters-in-username-password-for-http-proxy)

Option 2:
Set environment variable

HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.com:8080