# Git and http_proxy (SparkleShare on windows and http_proxy)

Tags: windows, git, share, http-proxy

I've just successfully built SparkleShare for windows according to guide:

https://github.com/wimh/SparkleShare/wiki

and exported my ssh public key to a server.
The problem is that I can't connect from a client behind a http_proxy to a public server with ssh running on a custom port. I had also problem with cloning any git server. I need to switch git:// protocol to http:// one. Any suggestion? Does anyone have similar experience?

This is a log file:

> 15:25:13 [SSH] ssh-agent started, PID=4380 Identity added:
>   C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\sparkleshare\sparkleshare.MYEMAIL.key
>   (C:\Users\sg0922706\AppData\Roaming\sparkleshare\sparkleshare.MYEMAIL.key)
>   15:25:34 [Fetcher][C:\Users\MYUSER\Documents\SparkleShare.tmp\share]
>   Fetchin g folder: ssh://MYGITUSER@MYHOST/MYPATH 15:25:34 [Fetcher]
>   Disabled host key checking MYHOST 15:25:34 [Cmd] git clone --progress
>   "ssh://MYGITUSER@MYHOST/MYPATH" "C:\Us
>   ers\MYUSER\Documents\SparkleShare.tmp\share" 15:25:37 [Git] Exit code
>   128 15:25:37 [Fetcher] Failed 15:25:37 [Fetcher] Enabled host key
>   checking for MYHOST

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7052613/33499 to configure a `git://` proxy. Of course your proxy server must accept that.

Answer (score 1):

To get SparkleShare to use your proxy you will need to modify the config of the msysgit that is installed as part of SparkleShare. Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\SparkleShare\msysgit\etc` and edit the gitconfig file in notepad and add the following line under the `[http]` tag

```
proxy = http://user:pass@proxyurl:port
```

modifying the url as required to match your settings. You can then use the "On my own server" option to add the http url of your repository.

Comment: for reference: https://github.com/hbons/SparkleShare/issues/1051#issuecomment-92917427

Answer (score 0):

I have a work around on this particular problem. I guess that you already successfully connected to your server via a simple SSH client (i.e. PuTTY)? With PuTTY you can easily configure an ssh connection via any kind of proxy (such as HTTP, SOCKS, Telnet, ..)

What you can do now is to specify a local "tunnel" (an SSH port forwarding rule) like this: L22 127.0.01:22 (see attachment). If you are using a ssh command line add the following option: -L 22:127.0.01:22.

[image: Local tunnel in PuTTY]

So now as soon as your terminal is open and running you'll be able to reach your git server via the server url: ssh://git@127.0.0.1.

If your local port 22 is busy you can define the tunnet on a other port. i.e. if the 44 is not occupied: L44 127.0.0.1:22. The url to use in SparkleShare become ssh://git@127.0.0.1:44.

[image: in SparkleShare]

But it's a work around. I'm looking for a better solution.