# Git for windows - unable to clone repository

Tags: git

When I attempt to clone a repository USING WINDOWS GIT (http://windows.github.com/) it consistently gets stuck on 9% complete. So all of the git specific files seem to be downloaded but the source itself is not.

I've tried updating the proxy settings within .gitconfig located at c:\users\username\.gitconfig to contain the proxy setting :

```
proxy=myproxy:myport
```

What could be causing this issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529218/how-to-use-git-behind-a-proxy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set a system variable where

```
name = https_proxy and value = <proxy name>:<port number>
```

For more info see accepted anwser + comments for [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)