# git:// through proxy

Tags: git, proxy, git-config

I'm behind a firewall that is blocking port 9418 (git) and am trying to install some tools that are explicitly doing a checkout of `git://github.com/...`, so I can't switch to https for the checkout.

So I'm wondering if it's possible to redirect all traffic to port 9418 through a proxy and if so how :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Have a look at `core.gitproxy` setting in [Git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Quick googling revealed this script that may be useful (or may not — I did not try it): https://gist.github.com/49288

Comment: Hm, interesting.  Would the questioner care to comment if this works, and if there are any downsides?

Comment: I actually am interested in this information as well, as I said I never tried it myself :-)

Comment: Please consider pasting the contents of this script, in case the file is removed.

Answer (score 92):

If you are talking about git submodules, try this:

```
git config --global url.https://github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/
```

...taken from [here](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/Git/Trouble#Firewall_Blocks_Port_9418).

This way, you don't need to set any proxy, nor run any script.

Comment: This is a super-elegant approach.  Worked quite well and didn't involve any crazy proxy nonsense.  I'd previously been able to just change the git:// URI but dealing with bundler in deployment made this a real nightmare.  Your solution is magically painless.

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me when a git:// url still didn't work after setting the http.proxy and https.proxy settings.

Comment: Also works with ssh: `git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf git://github.com/`

Comment: Works great for git://anongit.gentoo.org/ URLs behind a corporate proxy. Now I can use `layman` for overlays!

Comment: Edited the answer to add another possibility - Github is starting the SSH URL with `git@github.com:` instead of `git://github.com/` now, so you may need to change the end of the command to `git@github.com:`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make `core.gitProxy` point to a proxy command that will connect git to the remote server through your SOCKS proxy. You can create a script with the following content to serve as a proxy command:

```
nc -x <your_proxy_host>:<your_proxy_port> $1 $2
```

The two parameters, representing the remote host and port, will be passed to the proxy command by git. If you name this script `git-proxy` and make it accessible from your `$PATH`, you can call `git config` to set it:

```
git config --global --add core.gitProxy git-proxy
```

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried an ssh-based TCP tunnel?  If you have an ssh server that (a) is outside your firewall and (b) allows IP forwarding, you can do:

```
ssh -L localhost:9418:<remote>:9418 me@remote-ssh-server
```

or, if you have to run sshd on port 443 to get around your firewall,

```
ssh -P 443 -L localhost:9418:<remote-host>:9418 me@remote-ssh-server
```

Then, locally:

```
git checkout git://localhost/...
```

Obviously this isn't transparent, and it's a little convoluted - there are no doubt tools out there that are more specifically targetted at the problem.  However, I typically use this method because it uses tools I have to hand (ssh and a cheapo virtual server I rent).

(I've actually never tried this with a git connection, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work.  I've used it with many other single-TCP-port protocols without problem.)

Comment: Yeah, I can get a checkout on a specific repo working fine, but something out of my control is trying to do `git clone git://github.com/...`, so I can't do a proxy like that since I can't change the URL to `localhost`

Comment: You can try temporarily configuring github.com to be 127.0.0.1 in /etc/hosts