# How to connect to a git repository using the GIT protocol

Tags: git, git-config

I have my proxy that listen to `localhost` port `1233`
when I do clone I to https I changed the the http proxy and https proxy

```
 export http_proxy=http://localhost:1233
 export https_proxy=http://localhost:1233
```

and then clone to https worked for me from the proxy

```
git clone https://....
```

I want to do the same with clone with git protocol
   git clone git://

which environment variable do I need to change that the git protocol will listen to `localhost:1233`, I saw option with `insteadOf` but I prefer do use different way if it is possible

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git:// through proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860888/git-through-proxy)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22git%3A%2F%2F%22+protocol+proxy