# Git connection time out trying to clone via proxy

Tags: git, proxy

I am getting a connection timeout error when I try to clone a Git repo via a proxy server.

> git clone `http://opensource.freescale.com/pub/scm/imx/linux-2.6-imx.git`
>   Cloning into linux-2.6-imx...
>   error: Failed connect to opensource.freescale.com:8080; Connection timed out while accessing `http://opensource.freescale.com/pub/scm/imx/linux-2.6-imx.git/info/refs`
>
> fatal: HTTP request failed

I used corkscrew and set my git proxy to the server address and port. How else can I download or clone a Git repo over proxy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting git to work with a proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you do not need corkscrew for accessing a http repo behind a proxy server.

set the environment variable http_proxy

```
export http_proxy=http://<proxy>:<port>/
```

and then git will use the http proxy

see also http://roshansingh.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/using-git-behind-proxy/

Comment: I had set proxy via command: git config core.gitproxy filename        how can I unset this?

Comment: git config --unset core.gitproxy

Comment: I did an unset and tried again with error:git clone http://sw-git.freescale.net/linux-2.6-imx.git
Cloning into linux-2.6-imx...
error: Failed connect to sw-git.freescale.net:8080; Connection timed out while accessing http://sw-git.freescale.net/linux-2.6-imx.git/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed

Comment: I even explicitly did: git config --global http.proxy $http_proxy
......to no use

Comment: once I set http_proxy in the git config as above, I had to use the git site with http equivalent and it worked :) so am going to accept your answer

Comment: @user900785 thx, only using it explicitly helped me