# Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, socks

How to make git use a socks proxy for HTTP transport?

I succeed in configuring git with GIT_PROXY_COMMAND to use a socks proxy for GIT transport.

Also, I have configured my .curlrc file to defined the socks proxy and I can fetch information directly with curl command like:

```
curl http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
```

But how to use a socks proxy with git to retrieve data using the HTTP transport protocol like:

```
git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git
```

Comment: [patthoyts's answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228479/6309) will be officially supported in git 2.7 (Dec. 2015): http://stackoverflow.com/a/34118102/6309

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274879/how-to-contribute-on-github-anonymously-via-tor

Answer (score 195):

I tested with Git 1.8.2 and SOCKS v5 proxy, following setting works for me:

`git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:7070'`

UPDATE 2017-3-31:

[According to the document](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-httpproxy), despite the name **`http`**`.proxy`, it should work for both HTTP and HTTPS repository urls. Thanks @user for pointing out this.

UPDATE 2018-11-27:

To disable the proxy, run command:

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

EDIT 2019-03-04:

If you also want the host name to be resolved using the proxy, use thuzhf's solution below, which uses `socks5h` instead of `socks5`

Comment: brantyoung, Thank You! I forget to pay internet connection and had no external connection. I've used another server as gateway with: ssh -D 4000 <user>@server -p<port>, and succed to upload project to github over: git config http.proxy 'socks5://localhost:4000'. Thank You.

Comment: I'll get money and I'll pay for internet :), because project almost ready :)

Comment: How do I unset? do I set to ''?

Comment: @briankip open `~/.gitconfig` and remove `[https.proxy]` and `[http.proxy]` sections, its an `ini` file, feel free to edit it.

Comment: @briankip, I think you can just put it on the command line instead of permanently in your config, e.g. `git -c http.proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:7070`, or something like that. Maybe you could make an alias `gitsocks` to that, which would allow to you easily call git with and without socks as desired`

Comment: @briankip use `git config --global --unset http.proxy` to unset an entry

Comment: Are you sure that http**s**.proxy is needed? I don't find it in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: I was only able to make this work after changing the protocol to 'socks5**h**://<address>' (the 'h' stands for hostname resolution; see `man 1 curl`. "Makes it the equivalent of --socks5-hostname")

Comment: this solution don't work on git for windows, only work on mac and linux

Comment: it does work on windows, just don't forget the single quotes.

Comment: There is feature of ssh (>7.6) -R <port> if there is only port, then it make "oposite" socks5 proxy like -D, so traffic will come from "my" host https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#R~5

Comment: It doesn't have ``, `git config --global http.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:7070` is the correct syntax.

Answer (score 78):

If you do not want to set the proxy as global config, try `ALL_PROXY=` e.g.:

```
$ ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:8888 git clone https://github.com/some/one.git
```

Comment: Thank you! this really helps me while the global one doesn't.

Comment: Thank you! REALLY WORKS!

Comment: Thank you. Slight modification for me: ALL_PROXY=socks5h:...  (note the 'h' -- to do address resolution in socks server)

Answer (score 64):

(Just a little reminder) If you want the hostname also be resolved by the proxy (that means **passing everything through the proxy**), especially when you are cloning a **gist**, you can use the following setting (the key is that it uses **socks5h** instead of **socks5**):

```
git config --global http.proxy socks5h://127.0.0.1:1080
```

Comment: curl -x is ok ,but git clone  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 443: Connection refused

Answer (score 21):

I use the following command to clone a specific repository from socks5 proxy. The proxy settings are specified with `--config` option.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/xxxxx --config 'http.proxy=socks5://127.0.0.1:1234'
```

Comment: This is the only solution work for me, combo with 'ssh -D xxx'

Answer (score 8):

Note: the patch here was applied to git in 2015 for version 2.4.11. Since that time you can just use socks:// urls with the http.proxy configuration settings.

For the git:// protocol we have [Using Git with a SOCKS proxy](http://www.patthoyts.tk/blog/using-git-with-socks-proxy.html). However, it appears that git does not properly support socks proxies. git itself is linked to libcurl. So the .curlrc file is not used (that is just for the curl command line client). However, the following patch provides the necessary support. With this patch applied to git we can simply set the ALL_PROXY environment variable or HTTP_PROXY or HTTPS_PROXY to `socks://hostname:portnum` (or socks4/socks5) or indeed the http.proxy git config setting and libcurl will now actually use the socks protocol when using the proxy.

For example, an active trace:

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 bin-wrappers/git -c "http.proxy=socks://localhost:1080" ls-remote http://github.com/patthoyts/tclftd2xx.git
* Couldn't find host github.com in the _netrc file; using defaults
* About to connect() to proxy localhost port 1080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connected
* SOCKS4 request granted.
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 1080 (#0)
> GET /patthoyts/tclftd2xx.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: git/1.8.1.msysgit.1.dirty
... and on to a successful request ...
```

The necessary patch:

```
diff --git a/http.c b/http.c
index 3b312a8..f34cc75 100644
--- a/http.c
+++ b/http.c
@@ -322,6 +322,14 @@ static CURL *get_curl_handle(void)
        if (curl_http_proxy) {
                curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXY, curl_http_proxy);
                curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
+#if LIBCURL_VERSION_NUM >= 0x071800
+               if (!strncmp("socks5", curl_http_proxy, 6))
+                       curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
+               else if (!strncmp("socks4a", curl_http_proxy, 7))
+                       curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4A);
+               else if (!strncmp("socks", curl_http_proxy, 5))
+                       curl_easy_setopt(result, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS4);
+#endif
        }

        return result;
```

Comment: Like i wrote i successed in configuring git to use socks proxy for GIT transport. What i want is use git with a socks proxy for HTTP(S) transport

Answer (score 4):

Just in reference to @briankip and removing the http proxy setting as Yang.Y mentioned you can directly edit the ini file.

You can also do this on the command line using

`git config --global --unset http.proxy`

To confirm it has been removed list the current configuration using

`git config --list`

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked for me unfortunately, however this did:

```
nano ~/.ssh/config
```

Add:

```
Host my-host.foo.bar.com
    ProxyJump username@host.local
```

Where 'host.local' is a vanilla mac with 'remote login enabled' in the sharing settings. Worked for me :)

Comment: The original question is about http transport. Your solution is for ssh transport. Also, it's not using http proxy.

Answer (score 2):

### None of the suggested methods worked for me, so I found another approach as the following instruction:

---

1. Make a tunnel (dynamic port forwarding) over `SOCKS5` protocol using `ssh`:
   `ssh -ND 9994 user@YourSshServer`

---

2. Install `proxychains` on your localhost, not the ssh server you're connected to:

- Using `apt-get`:
  `sudo apt-get install proxychains`
- Using its [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng):
  <sub>Check *Installation* section on its readme file.</sub>
  <sub>[How to set socks5 proxy on firefox](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/532292)</sub>

---

3. Edit your `proxychains` configure file:
   `sudo nano /etc/proxychains.conf` then add the following line at the end of file:
   `socks5 127.0.0.1 9994`

---

4. Now we are ready to do a `git` command (`proxychains` must be placed before the command):
   `proxychains git push origin develop`