# Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?

Tags: git, github, proxy

Is it possible to configure git to use a proxy only for specific domains?

I'd like to use our corporate proxy to access Github but leave it off for accessing our own internal git repos.

I'm using bower and it needs to require items both within our firewall and on github so I can't do this as a per project setting. It needs to be some kind of global configuration option. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I usually use the environment variables:

- `http_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port`
- `https_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port`

That is picked up by git when accessing GitHub repo.

Note:

- both `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` must use the *`http://`* url of the proxy (no `https://`).
- always use the [fqn (full qualified name)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) of `proxydomain` (don't rely on its short name)

But for internal repo, all I have to do is define and export one more environment variable:

- `no_proxy=.my.company,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1`, for accessing any repo with an address like `myrepo.my.company` or localhost.

You can define `NO_PROXY` or `no_proxy`, it doesn't matter.

But just in case, I always set `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `NO_PROXY` and `no_proxy`.

Comment: In my case, it didn't work until I tried removing `http://` for both http and https.

Comment: no_proxy should not using * to wild match, use .mycompany.com instead will works.

Comment: @GuixingBai you are correct. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: what if  my password contains '@' in between?? any solution.?

Comment: @sheelpriy yes, use percent encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6172831/6309 (`%40`)

Comment: @VonC What does the `::1` do in the no_proxy statement?

Comment: @LightCC it ignores  the IPv6 loopback address `::1` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost, https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4291#section-2.5.3)

Comment: Any possibilities, if I want use `PROXYAAA` for domain `AAA` but `PROXYBBB` for domain `BBB` ??? 
in my case its for git pull, we have configured `.subversion/servers` with group for svn, but its ignored for git

Comment: @xxxvodnikxxx could my [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309) be helpful? For a certain server, you can set a certain proxy.

Comment: are you using Linux / Mac machine ? does this work with Git Bash on Windows ?

Comment: @Luke Windows, simple CMD, not even Git bash. This works across platforms.

Answer (score 81):

To add another possibility, you can [define a proxy through the `git config http.proxy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750116/6309).

```
git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:proxyport
```

But what is really neat is, [starting git1.8.5 (October 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb80ee09974667a1db6bbc5e33574ed869b76a88/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L69-L78), you can **set http settings per url**.

**The "`http.*`" variables can now be specified per URL that the configuration applies**.
For example,

```
[http]
   sslVerify = true
[http "https://weak.example.com/"]
   sslVerify = false
```

> would flip `http.sslVerify` off only when talking to that specified site.

---

See [commit d4770964d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d4770964d5058a679ebfc051acceb7968a831f84):

```
$ git config --bool --get-urlmatch http.sslVerify https://good.example.com
true
$ git config --bool --get-urlmatch http.sslVerify https://weak.example.com
false
```

> With only `<section>` specified, you can get a list of all variables in the section with their values that apply to the given URL.  E.g

```
$ git config --get-urlmatch http https://weak.example.com
http.sslverify false
```

---

All the details are in [commit 6a56993b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a56993b2ec7082521cf14f98ab9fb5a5def4b13):

```
http.<url>.*::
```

> Any of the http.* options above can be applied selectively to some urls.
>   For a config key to match a URL, each element of the config key is compared to that of the URL, in the following order:

- **Scheme** (e.g., `https` in `https://example.com/`).
- **Host/domain name** (e.g., `example.com` in `https://example.com/`).
- **Port number** (e.g., `8080` in `http://example.com:8080/`).
- **Path** (e.g., `repo.git` in `https://example.com/repo.git`).
- **User name** (e.g., `user` in `https://user@example.com/repo.git`)

> The list above is ordered by decreasing precedence; a URL that matches a config key's path is preferred to one that matches its user name.
>   For example, if the URL is `https://user@example.com/foo/bar` a config key match of `https://example.com/foo` will be preferred over a config key match of `https://user@example.com`.
>
> All URLs are normalized before attempting any matching (the password part, if embedded in the URL, is always ignored for matching purposes) so that equivalent urls that are simply spelled differently will match properly.
>
> **Environment variable settings always override any matches**.
>   The urls that are matched against are those given directly to Git commands.
>   This means any URLs +visited as a result of a redirection do not participate in matching.

Comment: To make specific domain NOT use the proxy settings, you need to set `http.proxy = ""`

Comment: How can you use a wildcard like *.mycompany.com to match all subdomains?

Answer (score 50):

As some have mentioned here, you can do this by specifying a URL along with the proxy settings, but Here's the use case that fixed this for me. Thanks to VonC above!

Notice below that I'm specifying the root of the Git server. The full path to the git repo you've cloned isn't required. You can use a single entry to take care of the entire server.

Add the following to your .gitconfig file. On my windows system, I'm using %userprofile%\.gitconfig

```
[http]
    proxy = http://my.proxy.net:8080
[https]
    proxy = http://my.proxy.net:8443
[http "http://my.internalgitserver.com/"]
    proxy = ""
```

Comment: You are welcome. +1. Note that you might have set the Windows environment variable `NO_PROXY` to `my.internalgitserver.com`, and that could have been enough to not use the defined proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229920/6309

Comment: Thanks, VonC. I'm in a situation where I'm creating several template config files for various proxied tools (git, bower, npm) and passing them out to team members. While you're right on the NO_PROXY setting working, it wasn't necessary in my case, and the simplicity of having these all in a single file that I can distribute is what I was after.

Comment: Good point. Distributing a file is easier than environment variables.

Comment: Even better - distribute a script or the direct git commands to apply the above. i.e. `git config --global http.proxy http://myproxy.net:8080`, for the first one, etc.  Then you don't even need them to find the right place to put or update the file.

Comment: @LightCC: Yes, that would work for sure; however, my particular use case requires the user's credentials be added to the URL: username:password@myproxy.net:8080, so that would complicate the script somewhat to include prompts and such.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for this answer, but I found its supported for git 1.8.5+, I am facing with  1.8.3, dont you know if there is some similar option? Thanks

Comment: Just FYI.... if you also have in the .gitconfig "[credential] helper = wincred" it will STILL pop up for the proxy... and then it won't use it, so don't be fooled by that window.

Answer (score 18):

You can adjust various configuration options for each remote specifically. Let's say we have 2 remotes, named `origin` and `upstream` respectively. You adjust the proxy for each doing the following:

```
git config --path remote.origin.proxy http://user:pass@proxy_for_origin:8080
git config --path remote.upstream.proxy http://user:pass@proxy_for_upstream:8080
```

This will change the sections of each remote inside your **local repository** configuration (`.git/config`).

You can also adjust the **global configuration** options if you wish. Since it doesn't make sense to reference a remote name in the global config file (`$HOME/.gitconfig`), you can use **url-matching** (IIRC, supported since Git 1.8.5). Example:

```
[http "https://example.com/repo1.git"]
    proxy = http://user:pass@proxy1:8080
[http "https://example.com/repo2.git"]
    proxy = http://user:pass@proxy2:8080
```

If you want to see what's been set:

```
git config --path --get-urlmatch https://example.com/repo1.git
git config --path --get-urlmatch https://example.com/repo2.git
```

Answer (score 13):

assume your proxy is (like my `ss`) is : `socks5://127.0.0.1:1086`

### config git proxy

- for all

  - **add**: `git config --global http.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1086`
  - **remove**: `git config --global --unset http.proxy`
- only for specific domain, eg: https://github.com

  - **add**: `git config --global http.https://github.com.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:1086`
  - **remove**: `git config --global --unset http.https://github.com.proxy`

#### Note

After added proxy, using

`cat ~/.gitconfig`

can see related global config:

```sh
[http]
        proxy = socks5://127.0.0.1:1086
```

or

```sh
[http "https://github.com"]
        proxy = socks5://127.0.0.1:1086
```

Comment: Use `socks5h` instead of `socks5` to send DNS through SOCKS5 proxy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756248/5380322)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, where i am behind my corporate proxy. I basically have two kinds of repositories:

1. External- which need proxy
2. Internal- which don't need proxy

I had to set a proxy in global config, which would act as the default, if not otherwise specified in local config.

So below are the commands for configuration:

set global config with proxy

```
git config --global --add http.proxy "http://username:password@proxydomain:port"
git config --global --add https.proxy "https://username:password@proxydomain:port"
```

then move to your local directory that contains your .git folder and for which you don't need proxy

```
cd "C:\Users\username\directory_without_proxy\"
```

set local config with empty proxy

```
git config --local --add http.proxy ""
git config --local --add https.proxy ""
```

It could be done the other way too. That is, you keep the global config as empty and local config with your proxy settings.

Just to double check you can use below command to list down the config settings for global and local respectively:

```
git config --global --list
git config --local --list
```

Answer (score -1):

On Windows , Simply [note without password] following worked for me

```
git config --global http.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:@myproxyserver:proxyport

git config --global https.proxy http://mydomain\\myusername:@myproxyserver:proxyport
```