# git cloning behind proxy -- different behavior, same command

Tags: git, clone

I researched for this problem but didn't find anything helpful. What I don't understand is that the error keeps changing. I am trying to clone a repository using

```
git clone http://git.osmocom.org/gr-osmosdr gr-osmosdr
```

and I get two different errors at different times:

1. Complains too many open files. (error: unable to ope object pack directory. fatal: failed to read object XXXXXXX: too many open files)
2. couldn't connect to proxy (couldn't connect proxy at mycompanyproxy (curl_result=7, http_code=0, sha1 = YYYYYYYY)

I did set the environment variable

```
http_proxy="mycompanyproxy:1080"
```

and

```
git config --global http.proxy mycompanyproxy:1080
```

I did verify values of the variables too.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: assuming your company uses proxy authentication (I hope they do), you should change second line to `git config --global http.proxy http://DOMAIN\\username:password@mycompanyproxy:1080`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting only environment variable *or* git config settings.

you can see both approaches set in "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309)"

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
```

Make sure to not use quotes, and don't forget the `no_proxy` one:

```
set no_proxy=localhost,.my.company
```