# Using Git on Windows, behind an HTTP proxy, without storing proxy password on disk

Tags: git, http, proxy, git-config

I'm using Git on Windows, on a corporate network where I'm behind an HTTP proxy with Basic authentication. Outbound SSH doesn't work, so I have to use HTTPS through the proxy.

I'm aware of how to use `git config http.proxy` to configure the settings as `http://[username]:[password]@[proxy]:[port]`.

However, particularly as this is a shared machine, I'd rather not store my password in my `.gitconfig`. Additionally, changing my `.gitconfig` using the `git config` command leaves my password in my bash history, so even if I remember to clear my `.gitconfig` at the end of the session, I'll almost certainly forget to clear my history as well.

I've tried setting `http.proxy` without a password, in the vain hope that I'd get a prompt asking me for my password when I try to push/pull, but I only get a 407 Proxy Authentication Required. All the information I've found online seems to either ignore the issues with having the password saved in plaintext in `.gitconfig`, or deals with NTLM proxies.

I'm quite happy to type my proxy details every time I need to connect - the best solution I can see at the moment is writing a wrapper script that will prompt for my password and set that as an environment variable when calling `git` proper. Is this a decent solution, and are there any security implications to setting an environment variable for a single call in a script? Preferably, are there any built-in settings or existing tools that I can use for this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instead of using git setting, you can also use environment variable (that you can set just for your session), as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309):

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
set no_proxy=localhost,.my.company
```

So your wrapper script could, instead of modifying the `.gitconfig` (and leaving your password in plain text) set environment variables on demand, just for your current session.

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799825/using-git-on-windows-behind-an-http-proxy-without-storing-proxy-password-on-di/22803427?noredirect=1#comment107466164_22803427) by [Welgriv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7758765/welgriv), this is unsafe since environmental variables can be accessed by any program in user mode.

---

These days (2020, 5+ years later), I prefer:

```
set http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
set https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
```

With 127.0.0.1:3128 being the default URL for a [**`genotrance/px`**](https://github.com/genotrance/px), a small HTTP proxy server, which will automatically authenticate through an NTLM proxy.
No password or even user to set.

Comment: Thx vonc *  I can use a *combination of your answer and the one offered by @0xA0 * -- easily change the value of the proxy in the environment and also use my WinCred to authenticated.

Comment: @HerbM Sure, both approaches are valid and, in your case, complementary.

Comment: It's unsafe since environmental variables can be accessed by any program in user mode.

Comment: @Welgriv I agree and I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. I have added as well an alternative solution.

Comment: @FernandoBrustolin I use the `px` approach (second part of this answer) every day without issues, on Windows, in a CMD or a bash session. Regarding [0xA0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3098740/0xa0)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534478/6309), please keep in mind that [`wincred` is obsolete: it is "`manager`" now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74665812/6309).

Comment: This solution did not work when using the "Git for Windows" MINGW64 "Git Bash." I took a different (but closely related to that of @0xa0) approach. E.g: `git-config --global http.https://github.com.proxy http://[user]@proxyhost:port` (see [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httplturlgt)).

Comment: Thanks for answering my comment @VonC. I read the second part of your answer, and I could go that way in some environments. Still, I leave a comment here because some people may need previous authorization to install and run software locally, as in my company's current policy. Fortunately, in machine's trusted in their network I do not need to authenticate against the proxy server and storing credentials is not an issue. Thank you so much for your attention to this question after many years.

Comment: @FernandoBrustolin No problem (after all, I am here [every day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309)). There is no setup/msi/intallation for `px`: it is just a binary that you launch and which is running in the background. No elevation of privilege required at any point.

Answer (score 67):

since git 2.8.0

```
git config --global http.proxy http://[user]@proxyhost:port
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Comment: Works for me. (from PowerShell console, without git bash)
To be explicit, "[user]" is replaced by the actual Domain\UserName (or similar).
I get an initial error when pushing/pulling:
    fatal: HttpRequestException encountered.
    An error occurred while sending the request. 
...but the command goes through and completes the push/pull.
thx  @0xA0

Comment: Though I also need:
https.sslverify = false

Comment: This is the best solution I've seen since most other suggestions involve either storing the password in plaintext or switching off `sslverify`.

Comment: This is slightly safer than store the password in an environmental variable since it can be accessed by any program in user mode.

Comment: For me `[user]` didn't work. I have replaced it with my username and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

VonC's answer doesn't always solve the problem. I don't know why, but it may depend on the proxy server - or maybe it's some other issue alltogether?

It may help to replace the `git://` protocol of the repository with `http://`.

Note: As in VonC's answer, you'll have to setup the `http(s)_proxy` environment variables first:

```
set http_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
set https_proxy=http://username:password@proxydomain:port
```

For example, clone marble's stable git would usually be cloned like this (from the [marble documentation](https://marble.kde.org/sources.php)):

> git clone -b Applications/15.12 git://anongit.kde.org/marble ~/marble/sources

In windows' `cmd` (assuming `http_proxy` has been set), you may then have to use `http[s]://` instead:

```
git clone -b Applications/15.12 http://anongit.kde.org/marble ~/marble/sources
```

Comment: This writes the password to disk, which is exactly what the question wants to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but thought I should add a note. In Windows 10, I did the above command in git bash as "git config --global https.proxy http://[userid]:[passwordWithSpclChars]@url:port" ... but since my credential has special characters, I had to then edit the config file C:\USERS<userid>.gitconfig  to URL encode the special characters in my credential.  Then I was able to proceed with git fetch from origin.

Comment: You can also percent encore the special character: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195690/6309

Comment: Yeah this still stores a credential locally.  The set environment variable setting however did not work for me though.

Answer (score -3):

**If you are behind Proxy server, follow this.**

Make sure port 9418 is excluded from your firewall rules.Ask network administrator

> Unset Proxy if it is already set:

- git config --global --unset http.proxy
- git config --global --unset https.proxy

> Set the proper Proxy:

- git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxydomain:port
- git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@proxydomain:port

> Common Errors:

- 502: URL/IP is unreachable from your network.
- 407: Proxy authentication Denied.
- 80 : Proxy has not been set properly.

Comment: This saves the password to disk, which the question specifically wants to avoid.