# Using Git on Windows not working when the password contain '@' Symbol

Tags: git, proxy, http-proxy

I am using following command

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myusername:mypassword@myproxyserver:8080
```

Here, mypassword has `'@'` symbol so it is not working
How can I resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your special character:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://myusername:mypa%40ssword@myproxyserver:8080
                                                     ^^^
                                                     %40=@
```