# failed to access github from proxy

Tags: windows, github

I have a github for windows installed in my Windows 10 system(it accesses internet from a proxy), and it works good previously.

Recently, my github can't connect the Internet (I'm pretty sure the proxy is set correctly since I didn't change it). After I re-install github, I can't login through the software with the correct username and password.

Since the proxy works in my Ubuntu OS, so I believe the problem is related to the proxy setting in windows.
However, the same setting has worked in windows for a long time and everthing just crushed recently.

Does anyone has any idea?

Comment: What console says?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub for Windows is called [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/) now.

Check [your environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20371843/6309):

```
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
set HTTP_PROXY=http://<login_internet>:<password_internet>@aproxy:aport
set NO_PROXY=localhost,my.company
```

(and launch GitHub Desktop from that same console, to inherit the variables you jsut set)

Comment: I have set the http_proxy, and I can confirm this setting with the cmd git config --global --get http.proxy, but I still can't connected to the server. What seems strange to me is that the error message is "login in fails", not "fails to access the server"

Comment: @Leo does your password include a special character?

Comment: yes, but I have use method in this linke to change the charactor, but still fails [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/277430/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-password)

Comment: @Leo yes, I mention that in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35195690/6309 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding