# bash script to clone/pull bulk git repo

Tags: git, bash, gitlab

I've several(22) private repositories on `gitlab` with `https` protocol and I want to checkout all repositories providing username and password once from bash script. But can't seem to make it work. Here's how far I got: (any edit/optimization is much appreciated):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "gitlab username: " user
read -sp "gitlab password: " pass
echo
read -p "branch to checkout: " branch
echo

repo[0]='.' #dir
repo[1]='repo.myhost.com/project/app.git' #repo url

repo[2]='plugins'
repo[3]='repo.myhost.com/project/app-core.git'

repo[4]='plugins'
repo[5]='repo.myhost.com/project/plugin1.git'

repo[6]='plugins'
repo[7]='repo.myhost.com/project/plugin2.git'

repo[8]='api-plugins'
repo[9]='repo.myhost.com/project/api-plugin1.git'

repo[10]='api-plugins'
repo[11]='repo.myhost.com/project/api-plugin2.git'

# will add more repo

total=${#repo[*]}
echo "checking out repositories..."
mkdir -p plugins
mkdir -p api-plugins

for (( i=0; i<${total}; i+=2 ));
do
    dir=${repo[$i]}
    trepo="https://$user:$pass@${repo[$i+1]}"
    echo "checking out ${repo[$i+1]} to directory $dir"...
    if cd $dir; then git pull; else git clone -b branch --single-branch $trepo $dir; fi
    echo
done
```

**Edit:**
My `git pull` doesn't provide any password, don't know how to do that. Also my password contains `@` in it.

**The outcome of this script:** asking for username/pass again

```
mamun@linux ~/dev/projects $ ./checkout.sh
git username: myuser
git password: 
project branch: master

checking out repositories...
checking out repo.myhost.com/project/app.git to directory ....
Username for 'https://repo.myhost.com': ^C
```

Comment: What is the error? Also if your `$user` or `$pass` contain special character you must `%`-encode them; `@` is `%40`.

Comment: it's asking for username & password again. let me edit the question.

Comment: Does cloning `http://$user:$pass@repo.myhost.com/project/app.git` work from command line?

Comment: It works that way. https://pasteboard.co/GJYZ29c.png

Comment: Run your script with "bash -x" and see what's wrong with URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, a password with `@` must be percent encoded (as I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35195690/6309)).
In pure bash, see this [function for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10660730/6309).

Try in your same bash those commands:

```
echo git ls-remote http://${user}:${pass}@repo.myhost.com/project/app.git
git ls-remote http://${user}:${pass}@repo.myhost.com/project/app.git
```

The ls-remote will query the remote repo branches, without pulling or cloning: this is just for testing.

The [OP Mamun Sardar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1342019/mamun-sardar) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167827/bash-script-to-clone-pull-bulk-git-repo/46168603#comment79308438_46168603) the encoding issue and adds:

> Also I made a mistake should use: `git clone -b $branch` instead of `git clone -b branch`

I agree and would recommend:

- using `${branch}` instead of `$branch`.
- checking your script with [www.shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: ok. I added `pass="${rawpass//@/%40}"` to replace. thanks. Also I made a mistake should use:`$branch` instead of `branch`

Comment: @MamunSardar Great! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility, and have added a link to check your script.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution would be to use SSH protocol with SSH key. If the key have a passphrase, you can use ssh-agent.

If you're stuck with HTTP(S), git provides a mechanism to give the username and password without putting them in the URL: [GIT_ASKPASS](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials)

`GIT_ASKPASS` is an env-var that points to a script that take one argument: the prompt ("Username for ..." or "Password for ...") and outputs the prompted value.
So a solution is:

```
GIT_ASKPASS=$(mktemp)
cat <<EOF > ${GIT_ASKPASS}
#!/bin/sh
case "\$1" in
    Username*) echo '${user}' ;;
    Password*) echo '${pass}' ;;
esac
EOF
chmod +x ${GIT_ASKPASS}

# Put here all your git calls that need credentials

rm -f ${GIT_ASKPASS}
```