# git clone from bitbucket repository failed due to proxy settings

Tags: git, proxy, bitbucket, git-clone

I had to change my  system  proxy settings while connecting to a public  network.I reset the system proxy settings,but git clone is unable to connect to any repository as it's  trying to connect through  192.168.128.1 port 8080,the earlier proxy setting which I had applied.I tried every possible method to change the proxy settings of both git through [Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oS7Z4.png) and the [System Proxy Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfwMv.png),but nothing seems to work.It would be great if anyone could suggest methods to correct this.I am on a system running on Ubuntu 14.04 with no firewall and no proxy server.

Comment: For the helpful folks,who downvoted my question, thanks a lot. The problem was solved by resetting the environment variable for proxy.

Comment: Note: your second picture is not the one of System Proxy setting... and shows your email. I will delete this comment once you fix the picture.

Comment: Thank a lot I have edited the picture.

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen, git config settings are not the only source of proxy configuration.

I prefer [setting environment variable myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22803427/6309), and [resetting them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6877747/6309) did solve the issue.

```
unset http_proxy
unset https_proxy
unset no_proxy
```

Don't forget you can set proxy for certain repos only:
See "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309)".