# Using Git exclude one host from proxy-rule

Tags: git, proxy

I'm behind a proxy and have to clone repositories from GitHub.
Therefore my `.gitconfig` file contains

```
[http]
  proxy = http://my.proxy:8080
[https]
  proxy = http://my.proxy:8080
```

This works great.

But what can I do if I want to clone a repo from a host inside my LAN, when I must not use the Proxy? In other words, I am searching for an exception rule like

```
[http "myhost"]
  proxy =
```

Sidenote: I would prefer a Git config solution (when it's possible), since I am working with multiple operating systems (Windows 7, Windows 8, Ubuntu, SuSE Linux) and the solution should work everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting [git 1.8.5 (Oct. 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bb80ee09974667a1db6bbc5e33574ed869b76a88/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.5.txt#L69-L78), you can do the reverse:

- specifying a proxy to be used for github.com only
  -not specifying a proxy for any other url.

See "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309)"

```
[http "http://github.com" ]
  proxy = http://my.proxy:8080
[https "https://github.com" ]
  proxy = http://my.proxy:8080
```

Comment: After updating to the newest Git version, this works like a charm. But I had to use the host "http://github.com", edited your answer accordingly.