# Exclude hosts or domains with git proxy

Tags: git, proxy, firewall

I use git behind a firewall and I need to configure

```
$ git config --global http.proxy
```

to handle connection.

But what happens if I only wanna avoid proxy for local domains?
I need the proxy for every host excepts for servers in my LAN.

There is a way to do?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067534/only-use-a-proxy-for-certain-git-urls-domains)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define an environment variable no_proxy in order to avoid the proxy for a specific domain:

```
no_proxy=.mycompany
```

The other approach, [since git 1.8.5+, is to set a proxy per url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309).