# Could not resolve host name bitbucket.org in git cloning

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am trying to clone a project in my local from bit bucket 
.But I am facing this fatal error
export fatal: unable to access 'some bit bucket url': Couldn't resolve host 'bitbucket.org'

I have also tried to use this command

```
$ git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

and referred to [These Url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377703/syncing-with-github/5378094#5378094)  but still no luck.

Can some some please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you do a wget or curl of https://bitbucket.org?

Comment: @VonC sorry I caould not make out anything

Comment: Do you need a proxy, and if yes, did you set it?

Comment: I am in my office network . So i presume I will need a proxy to set up can you proveide a link to set up this proxy

Comment: @If your office network has internet access, it means it already uses a proxy. Your Sysadmin IT should be able to provide with the url (or you can see it in the parameters of your browser)

Comment: That has nothing to do with bitbucket. I mean the proxy that you are using to access internet in general.

Comment: yes I use a proxy ? so is it he way I will set it up using gitbash
C:\> set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.mycompany:80
C:\> git config --global http.proxy %HTTP_PROXY%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100120/discussion-between-user2181397-and-vonc).

Comment: No need to set it in git, but you need to set HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/16069911/6309, with your username and password in it.

Comment: What country are you in?