# How to setup git to work with remotes that need different proxies?

Tags: git, proxy

I have some repos that I work with that are at the public github.com and require a proxy server from work.

I have other repos in our Enterprise Github instance that is behind the firewall and will fail when directed to our proxy.

What is the best way to manage this need for multiple proxies?  I can use `git config --global` along with setting the `http.proxy` and `https.proxy` keys to the proxy to get github.com repos connecting, but then Enterprise Github is broken and I have to clear those keys to get it working again.

How can I manage these two sources that require different proxy settings without manually changing the proxy?  Am I stuck using a script every time I switch projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I explained in "[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712501/6309)"
, you can set a proxy just for `github.com`.

But in your case, I would stick with the classic `HTTP(S)_PROXY` environment variable (no need for `git config` commands)

Simply add a `NO_PROXY` environment variable with the domain of your private Git hosting server, and Git won't use the proxy when cloning/pushing/pulling from said private server.

```
set NO_PROXY=.myserver.org
```

Comment: Looks good - thanks. I'll try it out the NO_PROXY solution next time at work and report back.  Will that work for the entire domain (i.e. `=.workdomain.org` - with the leading period) or do I need to specify the server exactly (i.e. `=gitserver.workdomain.org` - without the leading period?)?

Comment: I ended up avoiding the environment variable option (I've had issues with that before).  I tried a few different combinations, but just setting up github.com for the proxy made the most sense - it's currently the only external git repo I need to attach to, but otherwise you can set up the proxy for everything and then set the proxy to "" for the internal github address (both work).

Answer (score 2):

From [the link VonC gave to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16067534/6501141), I was able to put together the correct commands to get this done, but those answers are very convoluted (and sometimes difficult to understand the correct syntax), so I thought I would consolidate my answer here for posterity:

---

### Solution 1: Only apply the proxy to external site

One solution is to setup only github.com for the proxy with:

```
> git config --global http.https://github.com.proxy http://[user:pass@]<proxy URL>:<port>
> git config --global https.https://github.com.proxy http://[user:pass@]<proxy URL>:<port>
```

This looks a little funky because you are embedding `https://github.com` right in the middle of the normal `http.proxy` statement.  This is how you create a proxy that is attached to a specific site.

---

### Solution 2: Apply proxy to all, but remove it for internal site

Alternately, you can configure the proxy for all sites, then remove the proxy just for your internal Github site:

```
> git config --global http.proxy http://[user:pass@]<proxy URL>:<port>
> git config --global https.proxy http://[user:pass@]<proxy URL>:<port>
```

This applies the proxy to everything, and then do the following to tell Git to not use a proxy for your internal Git site:

```
> git config --global http.<Git Site URL>.proxy ""
> git config --global https.<Git Site URL>.proxy ""
```

where `<Git Site URL>` is the fully qualified domain name, such as `http://github.mycompany.com` - what you would type into the browser to get there.

---

### Notes

1. **The proxy address must be `http://proxy:port`, and not `https://proxy:port` (i.e. just `http`, NOT `https`)**, for both `http.proxy` and `https.proxy`.
2. There are other potential solutions, such as setting the proxy only for certain local repos, but not globally, or only setting the proxy for a given remote (say you have a repo with 2 remotes, one is external and the other internal), but I will leave those for the reader to determine...