# jspm and git share config

Tags: git, proxy, jspm, git-config

JSPM and Git are sharing share the same proxy value in my **.gitconfig**:

```
[http]
     sslVerify = false
     proxy = http://<proxy>:8080
```

I need the proxy value set when updating JSPM. I don't need it when updating Git (publishing to local Git server).

If I leave the proxy value set, I can't push commits. If I set "proxy= ", then Git works again, but JSPM doesn't.

Ideally I'd like to make them independent.

How can I get out of this wacky situation?

Comment: You might be able to do something with alias' or the no-proxy setting. Note I have used git but not jspm, so not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Confuzing for leading me in the direction where I found this:
[Only use a proxy for certain git urls/domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067534/only-use-a-proxy-for-certain-git-urls-domains)

```
[http]
     sslVerify = false
     proxy = http://<proxy-for-jspm>:8080
[http "http://<local-giterver>:8080"]
     proxy = ""
```