# How to config socks5 proxy on Git

Tags: linux, git, proxy

I have problem with downloading the git start link (git://anongit.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland) through a proxy on Linux OS.

I am using Git client (http://git-scm.com/download/linux) to download it, and it is successful to download the http link after I config the http.proxy in the `.gitconfig` file.

But I have tried a lot of ways to config the socks5 proxy for git link, but it didn't work. Does anyone know this?

More info on this:

1. I need to use a socks5 proxy with 1080 port.
2. There are username and password for this socks5 proxy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227130/using-a-socks-proxy-with-git-for-the-http-transport)

Comment: http://bardofschool.blogspot.com/2008/11/use-git-behind-proxy.html

Comment: [Using proxychains method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58952026/3702377)

Answer (score 7):

The patch mentioned by [patthoyts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291641/patthoyts) in "[Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15228479/6309)" will finally make it upstream in Git 2.7 (Dec. 2015)

See [commit 6d7afe0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d7afe07f29df75f831a46fb0f657fa37e561779) (26 Oct 2015) by [Pat Thoyts (`patthoyts`)](https://github.com/patthoyts).
<sup>(Merged by [Jeff King -- `peff` --](https://github.com/peff) in [commit 92b9bf4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92b9bf4a15346b8dae14772e07905ebb6ad29a47), 01 Dec 2015)</sup>.

> ### `remote-http`(s): support SOCKS proxies
>
> With this patch we properly support SOCKS proxies, configured e.g. like
>   this:

```
git config http.proxy socks5://192.168.67.1:32767
```

> Without this patch, Git mistakenly tries to use SOCKS proxies as if they
>   were HTTP proxies, resulting in a error message like:

```
fatal: unable to access 'http://.../': Proxy CONNECT aborted
```

> This patch was required to work behind a faulty AP and scraped from
>   [Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227130/#15228479) and guarded with
>   an appropriate cURL version check by Johannes Schindelin.

Comment: Does authentication with SOCKS proxies will be supported too ?

Comment: @EtienneProthon if this is used for the git protocol (as mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15228479/6309), then no: the git protocol has no authentication support.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer i will still use nmap to make this work