# Teamcity: ssh socks5 authentication

Tags: git, ssh, teamcity, socks

To get my git repo I need to connect to a proxy with socks5 authentication.

So i create a config file in *~/.ssh* and i use netcat to reach the proxy with the parameter `ProxyCommand`.

When i clone a repo in some terminal everything is fine.

But on Teamcity this doesn't work, it seems that it didn't use the config file.

So i try to use the [internal property](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Git#Git-InternalProperties) but there is no way to use socks5 with authentication.

If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you specify `teamcity.git.sshProxyType`, `teamcity.git.sshProxyHost` and `teamcity.git.sshProxyPort ` internal properties? What error do you get?

Comment: Test connection failed in myproject :: mybuild
List remote refs failed: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: ProxySOCKS5: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: fail in SOCKS5 proxy

Comment: Does your proxy require authentication?

Comment: Yes (the answer was in the title)

Answer (score 1):

Proxy which require authentication are not supported at the moment. Please watch/vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-12443.

Comment: Done.
But should i mark your answer as a solution or should i suggest my own solution (by using a script to create local mirror of git repo and then use ssh in this mirror in teamcity) ?

Comment: I dunno.. one can just use proxy without authentication

Comment: THat might be easier now that git 2.7 officially supports it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34118102/6309