# ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 7999: Connection timed out - Git for Windows

Tags: git, bash, github, ssh, proxy

I'm completely new working with repositories.

I have a repository that I need to clone from BitBucket (not BitBucket.org, the company where I'm working has an Enterprise BitBucket) using Windows 10 as Operating System.
I've followed the instructions given from [Attlasian Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html) but so far I have not been able to clone the repository because of the ***Message in the Title***:

```
ssh: connect to host x.x.x.x port 7999: Connection timed out
```

I've been researching, and the main reason is because I'm an under a proxy (company's proxy), so I setup the proxy as follow:

[Taken from this question - Getting git to workwith a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) and many more entries in StackOverflow

In Git Bash:

> I used the command

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

This command update the file `.gitconfig` located in the folder `%userprofile%` by adding this:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`
```

I have also tried the following, as some entries suggested:

```
[https]
    proxy = http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080`
```

In my PC:

I added the http_proxy environment variable with value "`http://myUser:myPass@myProxy:8080`", and also tried in many ways (`https_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, I was trying all of these because some question where answered by the ***UperCase*** issue or others had to add ***`https`***). The company proxy is *HTTP*, but the company repository is *HTTPS*.

Also, I contacted to the Network Manager (actually, not really sure about his position) and told me that I need to check the setup of the proxy because I'm trying to connect directly from my PC to the Host (not going through the proxy - see image), showing me this image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVcZR.jpg]

In order to corroborate if I am doing something wrong in any other configuration, I've made the same configuration explained in the Attlasian Documentation in my own PC (not from work) and without a proxy. I could clone the repository. So, the setup of the proxy is the problem.

So, I hope you can help me with this issue, I've been stuck for days researching about this, not being able to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you mention ssh: this has nothing to do with an https proxy.

ssh is normally on port 22, so make sure your ssh url used to reference your company's BitBucket repo is:

```
git@mycompany:myrepo.git
or:
git@mycompany:agroup/myrepo.git
```

if you still see mention to port 7999, check if you have a `%HOME%/.ssh/config` file which would force that port on ssh connection.
(`HOME` is generally set to `%userprofile%`)

But in any case, having an https proxy should have no bearing on an internal ssh connection.

Since ssh port is blocked, the OP had to use a socks proxy, following "[Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33077497/6309)":

```
ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:xxxx git clone https://github.com/some/one.git
```

It is [supported by Git since Git 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34118102/6309):

```
git config http.proxy socks5://127.0.0.1:xxxx
```