# Using Vundle behind Proxy

Tags: git, vim, proxy, vundle

We have have this neat little script at work that let's us use the internet over proxy from the linux enviroment. For example

```
withproxy git clone https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim.git
```

works just fine and doesn't even prompt me for my username and password.

How do I set this up within the `.vimrc` for Vundle so that all the git things are prefixed by this proxy script?

Comment: Have you tried just running vim with the proxy script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> How do I set this up within the `.vimrc` for Vundle so that all the git things are prefixed by this proxy script?

You don't.  What you do instead is make `git` go through the proxy:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080
```

You can also set the environment variable `http_proxy` to the same thing:

```
export http_proxy='http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080'
```

You might also need a `https_proxy` if you do it this way.

Comment: For socks proxy, just add `ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:1080` before the vim command. see, [using-a-socks-proxy-with-git-for-the-http-transport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227130/using-a-socks-proxy-with-git-for-the-http-transport#33077497). For example, I use [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) with `:PlugInstall` to install `wakatime/vim-wakatime`. I tried `ALL_PROXY=socks5://127.0.0.1:8888 vim`, then run `:PlugInstall` in vim and `vim-plug` will use the socks proxy. It works for me.