# Git clone to use ssh proxy

Tags: git, ssh

I am having trouble getting to use sock proxy when cloning using ssh url.
I am behind a firewall. I have made the below change to the config file:

```
Host git@bitbucket.org       
HostName git@bitbucket.org 
ProxyCommand connect -S proxyhostname:proxyPortNumber %h %p"
```

However when I clone I can see this error message:

> could not read from remote repository

I am new to this so not sure if there are any other configs I should be using.

Comment: you are mixing up terms. Do you want to use SOCKS proxy or proxy ssh connection. These are different things? Anyway you have wrong `Host` and `Hostname`, since it can't contain username as you have.

Comment: I would  like to configure git to use a socks proxy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227130/using-a-socks-proxy-with-git-for-the-http-transport)

Comment: And to create sock proxy, use `ssh -D localhost:9999 proxyhost`

Comment: Thanks but I already have a sock proxy. i would like that when i clone using basically the ssh repository url, i would like the requests  to be routed using the socks proxy. the link you sent he seems to be using a socks proxy for a http/https request.

Comment: This is the link I added in the second comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i removed the hostname and added a IdentityFile config to locate the location of the public key