# Is there any way to get git to work directly with a .pac (proxy auto-config) script?

Tags: git, pac

My corporate network works with a PAC script.(http://proxyconf.xxx.yy-ss/proxy.pac).

Using the PAC script in the "git config" command does not work.
 "git config --global http.proxy http://proxyconf.xxx.yy-ss/proxy.pac"

I got it to work by downloading the proxy.pac script (100 odd entries), selecting the most generic (usually the bottom most) proxy, and using it with my credentials in the "git config --global http.proxy" command.

I have already asked about making git work through a proxy server:

- [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)
- [How do I pull from a Git repository through an HTTP proxy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128035/how-do-i-pull-from-a-git-repository-through-an-http-proxy)

but the above questions make no mention of PAC scripts.

Is there some setting with which I can directly use the proxy.pac script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You would need to configure git and make it reference your own proxy server, one using your PAC file.

See for instance [**`liangqing/PacProxy`**](https://github.com/liangqing/PacProxy)

> A socks proxy server that use PAC file to decide how to forward request
>
> ### Features
>
> - Implement a socks server(support socks4 and socks5, no authentication module)
> - Using PAC file to decide how to forward request

As mentioned in "[Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756248/6309)", you need to configure git as:

```
git config --global http.proxy 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9999'
```

No need to configure `https.proxy`: [this does not exist in the Git codebase](https://github.com/git/git/search?q=%22https.proxy%22&unscoped_q=%22https.proxy%22).

Comment: @Peque Indeed. Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Installing nodeJs is a prerequisite of PacProxy. This is not exactly a lightweight solution IMHO :-(

Comment: @AttilaCsipak Agreed. I usually use https://github.com/genotrance/px/releases