# git: access git using proxy with .pac file

Tags: git, proxy

I have a pac file to access to proxy, I am using bitbucket.

http://xxx.xxx/xxx/proxy.pac same user of machine logged and password

I need git access to the repository.

Clone command is: git clone https://test@bitbucket.org/test/test.git

How can I configure it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to get git to work directly with a .pac (proxy auto-config) script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37343550/is-there-any-way-to-get-git-to-work-directly-with-a-pac-proxy-auto-config-scr)

Answer (score 0):

Compared to my [2016 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750992/6309), I now (June 2021) uses [`genotrance/px`](https://github.com/genotrance/px)

- you can launch it with a [`--pac=file` option](http://genotrance/px) or a [`.ini pac` directive](https://github.com/genotrance/px/blob/7e1cfd2dc2a2c925f0cf6c70388a8b4da7699ff5/px.ini#L10-L13).
- it runs on 127.0.0.1:3128 by default

That means your `HTTPS_PROXY` becomes `http://127.0.0.1:3128`

From there, you can access internet, and your BitBucket repository.

---

Note: the [PR 177 "feat: process noproxy rules even with `MODE_CONFIG_PAC`](https://github.com/genotrance/px/pull/177)" is being implemented (Q1 2023)

> When using PX in `MODE_CONFIG_PAC`, `noproxy` rules are ignored.
>
> This commit indicates required changes in order to have the expected behavior.