# Why my git proxy config does not work? I'm sure I've set it up correctly, but it still doesn't work

Tags: git, proxy

I use the following command to set the proxy

```
$ git config --global git.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
$ git config --global http.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
$ git config --global https.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080
```

But when I clone a repo, such as

```
# git clone git@github.com:npm/npm.git
```

It doesn't use the proxy to clone.

I try to change my proxy address, it is random address.

```
$ git config --global git.proxy asdfi:sidfw:sfd
$ git config --global http.proxy asdfi:sidfw:sfd
$ git config --global https.proxy asdfi:sidfw:sfd
```

If the proxy work, git should prompt some error.
But when I clone again，it didn't prompt any error

```
$ git clone git@github.com:s97712/protobuf.js.git
Cloning into 'protobuf.js'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/s97712/.ssh/id_rsa': 
remote: Enumerating objects: 1, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Receiving objects:   2% (363/18110), 60.00 KiB | 5.00 KiB/s
```

That mean the git proxy does'nt work.

I also tried to use the environment variable

```
$ export http_proxy="http://localhost:1080"
$ export https_proxy="http://localhost:1080"
```

But it still not work.

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone git@github.com:…
```

This is SSH protocol (scp-like URL syntax), it doesn't use HTTP proxy. To use proxy change the URL to HTTPS:

```
git clone https://github.com:…
```

PS. Port 1080 suggests that it's a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy. If it's I think the proxy syntax is different. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16756248/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+socks+proxy.

Comment: `git config --global git.proxy http://127.0.0.1:1080` can't work in `git@github.com:..` ? my proxy address 'http ://127.0.0.1:1080' can work on wget or curl, but can't work on git.

Comment: `wget` and `curl` use HTTP protocol, `git clone git@github.com:…` uses SSH protocol and SSH protocol doesn't use HTTP proxy, understand? To use proxy change the URL to HTTPs.

Answer (score 0):

I proxy my connections to github.com over a socks5 (`ssh`) proxy.

i.e. `ssh -C -D 1080 user@host -f -N` (`ssh` socks5 proxy through host in the background with no default command and compression enabled). My `~/.ssh/config` for github.com looks like:

```
Host github.com
    ProxyCommand /bin/nc -X 5 -x 127.0.0.1:1080 %h %p
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while upgrading from git client version 1.8.x to 2.x with same configs like you, including the environment variables. Like you said, nothing worked.

Solved it by adding an extra git config as below

```
git config --global http.proxyAuthMethod 'basic'
```

Can confirm the `http.proxyAuthMethod` config is required in 2.x version, but not in 1.8.x.

Hope this helps