# How to configure git's sock5 proxy to use remote dns resolve

Tags: git, dns, socks5

I configured the git proxy globally：

```
[https "https://github.com"]
    proxy = socks5://127.0.0.1:51837
```

However, when it was pushed to github, the connection was still abnormal. Through the opening log, I could see that although git uses socks proxy, it is resolved through the local dns, but the dns of github in my area was contaminated.

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git push origin master
```

The problem has been solved by configuring the correct ip mapping in the hosts file.
This should also be resolved by using a public dns.

But I still want to know how to configure the git socks proxy to use remote dns resolution？

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63228830/7976758 Or use something like [Dnsmasq](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html).

Comment: @phd Thanks for your answer, I found the solution in the corresponding comment section. Using 'socks5h' will use remote resolve, for example `git --config 'http.proxy=socks5h://127.0.0.1:4444'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socks5h` will use remote dns resolve, for example:

`git --config 'http.proxy=socks5h://127.0.0.1:4444'`

from [stackoverflow.com/a/63228830/7976758](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63228830/9785946) comments

Thanks @phd for the comment,