# How to make git work to push commits to GitHub via tor?

Tags: git, github, tor

So, GitHub is now officially banned by Russian Government and Rospotrebnadzor. I used GitHub to create free software and share it, and it's important part of my life.

Today I've installed Tor on Arch Linux and now I'm able to browse GitHub and other banned sites. I tried to make `git` work via Tor but without success.

Here is what I did:

```
git config --global http.proxy localhost:9050
git config --global https.proxy localhost:9050
```

But when I try to push, I get error `501`:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://X@github.com/X/X.git/': Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT

So, `501` means 'not implemented'. I have little experience with Tor (but from now on I'm starting to appreciate it), so don't know if it's really impossible to use Tor this way or I'm doing something wrong.

Q: how to configure `git` to use it via Tor?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274879/how-to-contribute-on-github-anonymously-via-tor

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server
And, as CQM suggested in the post linked by raina, it might be easier to just set up a VM whose only internet connection is through Tor. It might work without needing to proxy then.

Comment: For web browsing Hola plugin for chrome is a simpler and faster solution then tor. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hola-better-internet/gkojfkhlekighikafcpjkiklfbnlmeio?hl=en

Comment: @xvorsx, well, Tor also gives you privacy if you follow some rules. As far as I know Google Chrome is proprietary software. How can you believe you have privacy when you use proprietary software? I don't use Google Chrome because it would be the only software on my system that is not free (in terms of license).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a socks proxy with git for the http transport](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15227130/using-a-socks-proxy-with-git-for-the-http-transport)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to contribute on github anonymously via Tor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274879/how-to-contribute-on-github-anonymously-via-tor)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Setting an HTTP or HTTPS proxy will not work, because Tor acts on port 9050 as a SOCKS proxy. What will work instead is the software `socat` with some settings inside your SSH `config`:

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  IdentityFile /path/to/your/file
  User git
  ProxyCommand socat STDIO SOCKS4A:127.0.0.1:%h:%p,socksport=9050
```

Your SSH settings usually live in `~/.ssh/config`. The configurations above tell SSH settings for the host `github`. It takes your input and directs it via `socat` through Tor.

Now you can do a `git COMMAND ssh://github/USER/REPO` and git will do your `COMMAND` via Tor.

Comment: Nice solution, perhaps worth noting that the usual location of `IdentityFile` is `~/.ssh/id_rsa`. I actually did the same with Heroku. With Heroku you just need to create git remotes (`--ssh-git` passed to `heroku create`) as their default Git transport is thru http.

Answer (score 4):

It might be easier to install a VM as suggested, like [**Whonix**](https://www.whonix.org/) (also [on GitHub](https://github.com/Whonix/Whonix)), which will:

- take care of the Tor connection
- allow you to use Git with GitHub without having to define any proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do exactly that if there are no less complicated solutions.

Answer (score 4):

You used a wrong syntax, correct is:

`git config http.proxy socks5://localhost:9150 # 9150 for TOR browser, 9050 for TOR service
git config https.proxy socks5://localhost:9150`

Answer (score 1):

You could switch from `https`to `ssh`and use the tor `SOCKS` proxy in this way:

```
export SOCKS_SERVER=localhost:9050
git clone ssh://github.com/user/repo
```

Note that you need credentials when using `ssh`!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Tails OS](https://tails.boum.org/) and [PIA](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/). Both of these should keep you safe and free.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tool like `proxychains` to proxy a TCP connection via a socks5 server, that is a Tor daemon.

You've to install `proxychains`, on Debian based distros, you can do so with

 `$ sudo apt install proxychains` and you can look it up for installing on your specific distro.

Once you installed it, the default configuration file is located at `/etc/proxychains.conf`, you've to change the last line from `socks4 127.0.0.1 9050` to `socks5 127.0.0.1 9050`, this is not required but if you'd like to use socks5 features like stream isolation and such, it's needed.

And now, you can just do `$ proxychains git clone https://github.com/repo` or any git operation, and all these connections will go through the local socks5 server.