# Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org; nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: git, bitbucket

This error comes up every time I try clone any repo from Bitbucket using terminal:

```
$ git clone https://me@bitbucket.org/me/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'blog'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://me@bitbucket.org/me/myrepo.git': Could not 
resolve host: bitbucket.org; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I had the same problem with GitHub resolved by replacing 'http' with 'git' protocol which was great! But when I tried that on Bitbucket I got this:

```
git clone git://me@bitbucket.org/me/myrepo.git
Cloning into 'blog'...
fatal: Unable to look up me@bitbucket.org (port 9418) (nodename nor servname 
provided, or not known)
```

So I removed 'me@', making it the same as the actual webpage, and the operation just times out. Help?

Comment: bitbucket usually provides a link for cloning your repo through https or ssh, just go to your repo on bitbucket click the clone repo and copy/paste

Comment: Yeah, that's the code I started with.

Comment: does this link help any? https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/172218/error-could-not-resolve-host

Comment: The error `Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org` is probably due to issues with the DNS.

Comment: How would I fix issues with the DNS?

Comment: Try to clone with the IP instead the domain name bitbucket.org: 131.103.20.167.

Answer (score 1):

In your `~/.gitconfig`, is there an `[http]` section with a `proxy` entry in it? If so, that may be the source of your trouble. (I extracted this idea from a help page link posted above.)

Comment: For more information re the proxy see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server/19213999#19213999

Answer (score -3):

When cloning from Bitbucket via a terminal on mac osx, only http is supported, not https.

You should be able to use the exact same command just using http.

The Bitbucket repository overview webpage gives a clone command that includes https. On Mac, just remove the 's'.

Comment: We do not support http, only https and ssh (irrespective of OS). As mentioned by @antoan-milkov, this looks like a client-side DNS resolution issue.

Comment: I just tried it again. The fact is it works when running git clone and using the http url.

Comment: That's because we redirect you back to https.