# git clone from bitbucket.org is not working by https

Tags: git, clone, bitbucket

I am facing the same problem as [Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org; nodename nor servname provided, or not known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928722/i-cant-clone-a-bitbucket-repository-using-terminal). I have tried ip address given in comment, but it also gave the same message. Please, help to solve the issue.
Here is the error code:

```
    MYNAME@DEVELOPER8 /d/Projects
    $ git clone https://MYNAME@bitbucket.org/PATH/TO/REPO.git
    Cloning into 'REPO'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://MYNAME@bitbucket.org/PATH/TO/REPO.git/': Could not resolve host: bitbucket.org
```

Comment: If you can't use the hostname and you can't use the IP address, it would seem that you're not connected to the internet. Or does using a browser to surf to some sites work?

Comment: yes, internet is working fine. maybe it is network issue i have to solve?

Comment: The error 'could not resolve host' would imply that internet is not working fine. What did you test? Can you surf to https://bitbucket.org on the _same_ PC?

Comment: Thank You for the comments, my internet connection is not very good but i have surfed bitbucket.org several times and it opened without any problem.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy ? Is it enable and working fine in command line ? If you are under linux or git bash, try wget command on an adress using http, then https. It it fails, review your proxy config.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem. For sure it is not issue of internet speed or firewall. I have my private internet connection and on Ubuntu I have removed Network proxy as well.

Comment: I hope you have cleaned your network cache as you have removed network proxy recently

Comment: Use this syntax:

```git clone https://bitbucket.org/username/repo.git```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sometimes we make mistakes configuring our proxy.
Maybe this can help, reset your proxy.

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy
```

or one liner

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy https.proxy
```

Comment: Please provide more explanation than a code snippet. It may be obvious for us, but help others letting them know why this code answer the question

Comment: Sure, I can do my best... @Jean-RémyRevy

Comment: Here's a one liner for lazy people like me :) 
git config --global --unset http.proxy https.proxy

Comment: Thanks @Waqas, I added it to the answer

Answer (score 3):

When you create a repository in bitbucket, the user interface displays the exact clone command you need for you:

[image: a busy cat]

So, your clone command would need to be:

https://usersname@bitbucket.org/username/reponame.git

Comment: Not sure why but seems like the org level username I had in my clone command copied directly from their website did not work, I removed that username part from the url and it worked for me.