# Error using cordova CLI to search or add plugins

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-cli

I am using Cordova version 3.4.0-0.1.3 on Windows and using the command-line interface (CLI). I have successfully built a simple test app and run in the Android emulator. But when I now try to add a plugin to my app, I receive an error. Even trying to search for a plugin fails. I am afraid that there is a problem since I am behind a corporate firewall - but I set the proxy, http-proxy and https-proxy settings.   Also, I am not clear as to whether I need a git command line interface also installed (I don't believe this is required).

When I run, for example, "cordova plugin search device", I receive the error:

> Error: connect ECONNREFUSED   at errnoException (net.js:904:11)   at
>   Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)

And when I try to install a plugin using, for example, "cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device", this fails with:

> Fetching plugin "org.apache.cordova.device" via plugin registry Error:
>   Failed to fetch package information for org.apache.cordova.device
>       at C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plug
>   man\src\registry\registry.js:32:20
>       at Request.cb [as _callback] (C:\Users\71476\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
>   s\cordova\node_modules\plugman\src\registry\registry.js:251:9)
>       at self.callback (C:\Users\71476\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\no
>   de_modules\plugman\node_modules\request\index.js:148:22)
>       at Request.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
>       at ClientRequest.self.clientErrorHandler (C:\Users\71476\AppData\Roaming\npm
>   \node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\request\index.js:257:10)
>
> ```
> at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
> at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1547:9)
> at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
> at net.js:440:14
> at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
> ```

Is there any way to verify that the proxy setting is correct?  Any ideas what else I can check for?

Comment: Try setting NPM proxy: http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy
and GIT proxy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 0):

try remove and add it back.

```
cordova plugin
cordova plugin rm org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
```