# Connect to git repo on Visual Studio Online

Tags: windows, git, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm trying to connect to a **git repository on visual studio online using git for windows** (the one provide by visual studio on team explorer).

I enabled **alternate credentials** but no matter what I do I got the following message :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/******/_git/SIT-Prototypes/': Failed connect to xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com:443; No error
```

I tried the following command lines :

```
git clone https://xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/******/_git/SIT-prototypes

git clone https://username:password@xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/******/_git/SIT-prototypes

git clone https://xxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/******/_git/SIT-prototypes -u=username -p=password
```

Anyone with a miracle solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you work with a proxy ? If so, you should use the command `git config --global http.proxy http://@yourproxy.com:port`

I don't see any other mistakes which could lead to these errors if you actually enabled the alternate credentials...

Comment: For VSO you'll actually want to set the https.proxy not the http.proxy config setting.  Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server for more informtion on using git behind a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for both of your answers. Now everything is working as wanted.