# Repository test is failed when I clone git repository in Android Studio on Windows

Tags: git, android-studio

Since Eclipse is out of support I am migrating my Android projects under Android Studio. All my projects reside on Raspberry Pi and I was succeeded with cloning all projects on Linux machine. However I am getting the error under Windows 8.1.

[image]
Eclipse didn't have any problem to work with the same URL and host is reachable using ssh client.
What can be a problem?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who is looking for answer that anything else didn't help:

My problem was due to 2 users in Github in the Keychain so I removed the password of the other user of my Github account and that solved the problem.

Good luck

Comment: You're awesome. I owe you big time. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use smart github from terminal.

Try it out on a public repository:

$ git clone http://github.com/schacon/grack.git
For private repos, or to have push access on your repository, you can clone this way:

$ git clone https://username@github.com/username/project.git

Answer (score 2):

This is a great example of an error message that is not much help.

Is `git.exe` available to Android Studio?

In **Settings > Version Control > Git** there's a `Test` button to see if git runs properly.

In my case, it wasn't visible (not installed). See http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html for advice on how to install it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably going to come out late, but I installed a new version of android studio and wanted to import from github and ran into the same problem.

My solution was, from the wizard that pops up when android studio is first run, go to Configure > Settings > Version Control > Github and then specify my github account.  Then importing from git worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

first check cloning from your git-bash ... run your git-bash(if you installed) and then go to a folder that you want reposite your project, for example:

```
cd c:/myfolder
```

in your git bash (the directory must be created before). after that you can write a correct example url and clone statement:

`git clone https://bitbucket.org/csgerber/reminders-git.git`

this example url is correct and i test it. after a while in "myfolder" you must have the reminders project. if this method worked properly, you may not have any problem to do this in your android studio. however i coudn't because in my location, i coudn't connect to some server (for internet filtering) and i should use a proxy like freegate. so i need to set git for the proxy like this answer : [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before and I solved it by unchecking the option "Clone git repositories using ssh" from Settings > Version Control > Git