# git push to TFS server over VPN connection

Tags: git, tfs, vpn

I have a `git` project hosted on a TFS server (ruling out `ssh`protocols). After setting `git config --global sslVerify false` I was able to `git pull` and `git clone`, but over a VPN , I was unable to `git push`.

To be more explicit, `git clone https://tfs.example.com/project.git` clones the repository without problem, but `ping tfs.example.com` times out with no response.

I have used the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server) question to make git aware of my proxy settings, but even with this set, `git push` still terminates with

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://tfs.example.com/project': Could not resolve host: tfs.example.com
```

Other perhaps relevant information: git --version 1.9.1, Ubuntu 14.04, running through an Oracle VMWare virtual box, hosted on Windows 7.

Any suggestions? In any case, I'd be happy just to figure out why there is an asymmetry between `git push` and `git pull`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the protocol to git and then clone/pull/push.

HTTPS is a little bit different then http and git. you can read more about the differences **[here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols#The-Smart-Protocol)**

Using ssh (or git://...) will ensure that you using the ssh keys on your machine and might solve your problems.

Using HTTP/HTTPS you might need to use your username password in order to push changes, while with git/ssh you don't need to do so.

It looks like you are able to pull/fetch and you get a read-only project without the ability to push back changes. try switching to git/ssh and again it should solve this issue.