# Android Studio unable to connect to Github via proxy

Tags: android, git, github

**Environment Info**

```
Windows 7 Enterprise OS SP 1
Android Studio AI-141.1972460
Build #AI-141.1972460, built on June 1, 2015
JRE: 1.7.0_80 b15 amd64
JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
```

Access to internet is via corporate proxy server

**Expected Behavior**

***Location:*** 
***Version Control-->Github***  configuration panel

1.When valid github account and password fields are populated clicking on **Test** connection button should result in successful connection confirmation to Github.
2.When selecting ***Share Project on Github***  project successfully connects and uploads project files.

**Problem**

Can not share project via Github via ***Share Project on Github***
Following error is reported when clicking on ***Test*** and when selecting
 menu option

**Error Indicated**

```
Can't login: Connect to api.github.com:443
```

**Additional Details**

1.Proxy is correctly configured via Android Studio. SDK, SDK tools and plugins are successfully downloaded.

2.Git commands work successfully from a windows command prompt and via Android Studio's Git Menu Options.

Successful commits, and push via Android Studio work successfully, after first creating repository via Github website.

However via ***Test*** button and ***Share Project on Github*** menu option fails with the error indicated above.

I understand that this error is indicated when proxy is configured and Github plugin access is not configured for proxy (However I see no way of setting proxy, I assumed that proxy settings are global for all plugins in Android Studio).

Please help me resolve this issue. I using Git menu options so it is not a showstopper but it is still very frustrating.

I entered Bug Report **Issue 175831** [Android Open Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175831) site

Answer (score 8):

Try setting proxy for git using commands:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy https://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/1436766) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting proxy for git using following command. It helps me.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxy.mycompany:8070
git config --global https.proxy https://proxy.mycompany:8070
```

where 8070 is port number.