# Unable to push the code on bitbucket - Port 443 issue

Tags: git, proxy, push, bitbucket

I am not able to push the code on bitbucket. 
When I run this command "git push origin branch_name", then it gives error -

fatal: unable to access 'https://user@bitbucket.org/folder/project.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Network is unreachable.

How to resolve this. Someone help ?

Answer (score 5):

## Solution 1: Update hosts file

Add bitbucket.org IP to `/etc/hosts` file (It's work for me)

```
104.192.143.2 bitbucket.org
```

## Solution 2: Config proxy server

Command to use:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

- change `proxyuser` to your proxy user
- change `proxypwd` to your proxy password
- change `proxy.server.com` to the URL of your proxy server
- change `8080` to the proxy port configured on your proxy server

If you decide at any time to reset this proxy and work without proxy:

Command to use:

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Finally, to check the currently set proxy:

```
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

More details on [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/5456204)

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to reach Bitbucket from that specific server, either through a browser or using a tool like curl? "Network is unreachable" is a pretty strong indicator that something is wrong, either in the network configuration on that system or in the network between that system and Bitbucket.