# Unable to access in Github through Git bash (Time Out Error)

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I want to execute the following command using Git Bash on Windows:

```
git push -u origin master
```

But it continuously gives the following error:

```
> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/aaabb/XXX3.git/':
> Failed to connect to 172.30.0.7 port 3128: Timed out
```

Any suggestions?

*(I hid my username and project name from the above.)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems your are behind proxy server and you do not use authentication. Look at this: [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)