# Proxy connect aborted while accessing git

Tags: git, laravel, proxy, git-clone, http-proxy

I'm trying to clone the following repo using command :
git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git

And I'm getting following error:

```
Cloning into 'laravel'...
error: Proxy CONNECT aborted while accessing https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
fatal: HTTP request failed
```

What is going wrong ?

Comment: have you check your username and password for this git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm behind the proxy, when I setup git to use proxy, like it is stated in this answer: [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

I could correctly cloned that laravel repo