# Julia connection to server behind proxy

Tags: proxy, julia, atom-editor, windows-firewall

I have a problem with the connection of Julia and Atom to the servers.
My location is currently in a company network which works with proxies and firewall. Does anyone have any idea what settings I must change in order to connect with Julia and Atom servers?

Because, if I use my home network everything is running fine. I can also start Julia at my home on my work computer and it is running at work until I start it again at work.
Here is an example of an exception I receive while trying to install any package at Atom:

```
connect ETIMEDOUT 54.235.138.91:443
```

Here is an example of an exception I receive while trying to install any package:

```
Julia> Pkgupdate()

 INFO Updating METADATA… Fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
 Github.com[0: 192.30.253.113]: errno=No error

 ERROR: failed process: Process(‘git pull - -rebase –q’,
 ProcessExited(1)) [1] in pipeline_error at process.jl:555
```

Does anyone knows what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting your global git proxy config? See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 1):

While it may not solve your particular issue (if you use Julia v0.4), for the sake of future readers:

In v0.5 or later (more specifically, after https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/17783 was merged), Julia will respect the standard `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `http_no_proxy` environment variables through `libcurl`. It is possible that certain packages still do not respect these environment variables; I would file an issue with the package in question in those cases.

Comment: I am on `v0.5.0 ((2016-09-19 18:14 UTC) x86_64-linux-gnu` and I am still seeing this error (for the command `Pkg.add("DataFrames")`). I *can* pull the required URL (`curl https://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl`) using curl in the console (and even the Julia `shell>` prompt).

Comment: @StephenMcAteer What are the values of your `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `and `http_no_proxy` environment variables?

Comment: I am behind a corporate firewall, using `cntlm` as a proxy server. The env vars are set correctly for this. (Like I said, curl is working out in the wild).

Comment: Julia installs it's own version of curl, which by default does not support using the proxy.