# Unable to connect to github with git

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

I have problems connecting to my github repository.
I set up the github repo as a remote of my local repo with the URL https://github.com/Koefflitz/Util.git.
When I type: `git fetch` I receive a 403 error:

"fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Koefflitz/Util.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403"

So I tried it via ssh:
`git remote set-url github git@github.com:Koefflitz/Util.git` and then `git fetch`. There I received this message:

"ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

I guess it has something to do with DNS, but I don't know why this happens. With the browser I can access the github repo without any problem.

I am behind a proxy, so I configured my git proxy settings with "http://myUsername:myPassword@myProxy:80". I set `sslVerify` to `false`, because of self certified certificates, that cause problems.
My OS is Windows 7, my git version is "2.7.1.windows.2" and the DNS server I am using is 2.136.34.2

Why is it not working and why do I get these error messages? What can I do to get access to my github repository?

Comment: What happens if you do `ping github.com` ?

Comment: It takes a while and then I get a message that means: "Ping request could not find host \"github.com\". Check the name and try again."

Comment: Refer the selected answer to this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Comment: What about `nslookup github.com` ? Basically, can you access github.com from your computer at all? The problem may not be git-related.

Comment: When I do `nslookup github.com` I get a timeout. But I can access it with my browser....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting git to work with a proxy server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Comment: The proxy is configured in git as described in my question above. I don't see that it's wrong somewhere. When I type `git config http.proxy` I get the correct proxy settings.