# Git cloning URL vs Host Url

Tags: git, proxy, azure-devops, git-bash, http-proxy

I am trying to clone a repository using Git-Bash to my account in a server. There is no access to the internet for this server, except to the the account "myvsaccount.visualstudio.com".

When cloning, even though I use the whole url "https://myvsaccount.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/repo/"

wireshark and fiddler tell me that the cloning to the URL above actually hits "myvsaccount.visualstudio.com". So I am guessing it should work. But I get the error:

> fatal: unable to access
>   'https://myvsaccount.visualstudio.com/Project/_git/repo/': Could not
>   resolve host: myvsaccount.visualstudio.com

As if the host does not exist or I don't have access. Do I have to open the server to the internet, now opening to all cloning URLs for it to work? I didn't think I would need to do that.

Also, I am using a proxy configuration [System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy = new-object System.Net,WebProxy($proxyUri, $true), but it is not helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should config Git to use the proxy, the command to config as:

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

Then you can clone again to check if it can clone successful.

More details, you can refer [Configure Git to use a proxy](https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765#configure-git-to-use-a-proxy) and [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server/19213999#19213999).