# unable to access repo: OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to github.com:443?

Tags: git, ssl, github, git-clone

[image]
[image]

I didn't set proxy on computer.I tried `git config --global --unset http.proxy`,didn't work.

Wireshark capture shows connection reset by github.com(in my case,github.com was resolved to 192.30.253.113)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51433565/7976758