# how to use git with psiphon vpn

Tags: git, vpn

I am using psiphon vpn desktop for windows10 and when i try to push to my git repo it shows me an error

```sh
git pull --tags origin master
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alsong/Trial.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out

```sh
git fetch
```

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/alsong/Trial.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com

It doesnt even allow me to use npm functions. I have really tried to find out the solution for this though they still dont work.

I would be grateful for the help

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to configure npm to use your proxy then. Here are the relevant configuration variables:

- [proxy](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy) [https-proxy](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy) [cafile](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cafile)

I think you might have to configure git to use the proxy as well. Here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49345357/fatal-unable-to-access-https-github-com-xxx-openssl-ssl-connect-ssl-error) for that.