# Options to access VSTS/Azure Devops through a corporate proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, azure-devops

We are moving from an internal Git server to an external service.
I have set up a project in Azure DevOps and I'm attempting to clone the repo to my local machine behind a corporate proxy.

When I run the clone command with the URL from Azure DevOps, I get the following error:

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://user@dev.azure.com/user/project/_git/project/': 
Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT
```

As far as I can see, Git is set up correctly with the proxy details already (it appears with the right proxy address when I run `git --global-config --get http.proxy`)

From some Googling around, the proxy might be incapable of giving access to external Git.

The proxy may (will likely) be out of our control; what other options do we have for connecting to an external repo with normal git commands (fetch, push, pull, etc)?

There is a similar question here: [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server), however that times out whereas mine returns instantly with a specific error message (`Received HTTP code 501 from proxy after CONNECT`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting git to work with a proxy server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server)

Comment: @rickvdbosch thank you, that didn't show in my search. Their error is different to mine and the accepted answer is to set the proxy (which is set correctly already for me).