# Error when trying to clone git repository

Tags: git

I'm trying to learn how to use Git. I created a folder, and I wanted to clone a Symfony repository. I was told to use :

```
git clone http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
```

But then I get :

```
Cloning into 'symfony'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://github.com/symfony/symfony.git/': Failed to connect to github.com port 80: Timed out
```

I can't see why I get this error and how to solve it. I tried to clone another repository like Angular, but I get the same error.
Does someone knows how to solve this ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: Well, actually I think so. Does that change anything ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999/8718377

Comment: Thank you so much ! I'm going to take a look at that :)