# Git can't clone repo because of 403 error

Tags: git

I am trying to clone some repo from GitHub, but I am getting error like:

> fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/some/thing.git/': Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT

I am behind corporate proxy, but I set it already in `.gitconfig`.

This is inside my `.gitconfig`:

```
[http]
    proxy = http://something.com:80

[https]
    proxy = http://something.com:80
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't think https can be proxied to port 80. Try `proxy = https://something.com:443` instead?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Tried. Still the same response.

Comment: Consider having a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403 so proxy has undestood request but refused to perform operation for some reason. Contact your IT department to get proper configuration and proxy limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If your proxy needs credentials, add your credentials in proxy URL. You can try using running this command in cmd.

```
git config --global https.proxy http://username:password@host:port
```

This command is going to update your .gitconfig file as below.

```
[http]
proxy = http://username:password@host:port

[https]
proxy = http://username:password@host:port
```

Comment: Missing credential for proxy should lead to HTTP status code 407 not 403.