# Firewall issue installing npm package in angular

Tags: angular, github, npm

Due to the firewall at work (at least that's what I think it is...) I cannot download an `npm package` required by my angular project from github. It throws an error saying that it cannot connect to github and the file or directory does not exist. The repo is [`https://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components#v1.0`](https://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components#v1.0) and it does exist. Is there a way around getting this to work except for waiting for my support department to get me through the firewall, they seemingly have not had time to look and I am stuck...

I added `"ecl3d": "git+https://git@github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components.git#v1.0"` to my package.json and ran `npm i` with no result so far. I have asked the support department and they are seeing me ping a request to github.com[0: 140.82.118.4] but are not allowing it.

```
PS C:\Users\tassc\Projects\Configurator> npm i
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t git://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! github.com[0: 140.82.118.3]: errno=No such file or directory
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\tassc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-20T09_51_53_197Z-debug.log
```

The error file generated https://hatebin.com/itpujucggp

Comment: try this way:`"ecl3d" : "git://github.com/cmelange/ECL-3D-Components.git#v1.0"`

Comment: Has the same result, I have edited in the console error and log file for reference.

Comment: did you set proxy config?

Comment: I dont even know what that is or how I should do that.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783811/getting-git-to-work-with-a-proxy-server-fails-with-request-timed-out

Comment: Not sure about the relevancy of this as its about git and I am trying to use npm. Or does npm use my git settings somehow?

Comment: npm uses the git clone command internally to download the packages needed during installation. So if you are behind a proxy in your organization you need to configure it likewise.

Comment: Alright, I will need to check the configuration on that. Will try the link you posted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206279/discussion-between-wisely-d-cruizer-and-torben-van-assche).