# unable to remove proxy settings in vcs android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, github, http-proxy

I'm currently using my mobile Internet to push my android studio project to github while doing that I'm getting unable to connect to 10.20.3.11. which I used before in android studio to connect to Internet.
I set that proxy to noProxy in settings and also removed proxy settings in gradle.properties(global properties) and also restarted androidstudio many times. but when I add new dependency gradle synced properly and added that dependency too. still facing proxy problem while pushing project
help me I'm using ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your git settings are looking at a proxy already set. You can check for which proxy settings your git is configured with using the following command;

```
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

You can clear the git proxy configs using;

```
git config --global --unset http.proxy
```

Refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19213999) for more info;

Comment: Thanks, I did it before but nothing changed. And I came to know this error is only in Android studio 3 in ubuntu platform only